# How to find the remainder of a division in C?

Tags: c, division

Which is the best way to find out whether the division of two numbers will return a remainder?
Let us take for example, I have an array with values {3,5,7,8,9,17,19}. Now I need to find the perfect divisor of 51 from the above array. Is there any simpler way to solve this?

Comment: I find the range `{3,5,7,8,9,17,19}` quite suspicious. It *almost* looks like you're using primes here, but 8 isn't prime and 11 and 13 are missing...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator to find the remainder of a division, and compare the result with `0`.

Example:

```
if (number % divisor == 0)
{
    //code for perfect divisor
}
else
{
    //the number doesn't divide perfectly by divisor
}
```

Comment: Modulus and reminder are different for negative numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder

Comment: good point, but I don't see how that changes the check for perfect division

Comment: The answer is fine regarding to the question, but the C is very fuzzy about the relation between %, modulo and remainder operators, and your statement was just a bit imprecise, so I just added a link to clarify this point.

Answer (score 11):

Use the modulus operator `%`, it returns the remainder.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

if (a % b != 0) {
   printf("The remainder is: %i", a%b);
}
```

Comment: @Joey - why did you remove the example?

Comment: I didn't; I just corrected a typo and added the operator sign. Could be that simultaneous edits were clashing here. SO is even poorer at that than MediaWiki. I.e. when I was editing it I only saw the one sentence and didn't get a notification either on concurrent modification. Sorry :/

Comment: My apologies... I thought you had some problem with my example... And thanks!

Comment: But it's inverted? for example: 12 % 8 = 4, that's what it should be. but 11 % 8 = 3 when it should equal 5.

Comment: @MarcusJ - `11 % 8` equals 3, not 5. as `11 = (8 * 1) + 3`.

Comment: Yeah, I said that it equals 3. for my purpose it should equal 5 (I know how crazy that sounds) because I'm trying to find how many bits until the next byte.

if you have read 11 bits, there will be 5 left over until you hit 16, or 2 bytes.

it seems like 11 % 8 should work, because 8 is the number of bits in a byte, but apparently I'm getting something wrong.

Comment: Actually '%' returns the modulo, not the remainder, which is different for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are correct. Just providing with your dataset to find perfect divisor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

int arr[7] = {3,5,7,8,9,17,19};
int j = 51;
int i = 0;

for (i=0 ; i < 7; i++) {
    if (j % arr[i] == 0)
        printf("%d is the perfect divisor of %d\n", arr[i], j);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP should probably clarify whether 3 or 9 should be considered the perfect divisor in those cases. I assume 9 because otherwise there is no point in it being in the array. In which case you'd need to loop in reverse order.