# What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?

Tags: c, math, operators

My friend said that there are differences between "mod" and "remainder".

If so, what are those differences in C and C++? Does '%' mean either "mod" or "rem" in C?

Comment: It probably is ill-defined for negative operands.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Do you means that difference depend on implementations when occur negative operands ? I need "yes" or "no" because this question make a trouble to me. Thanks!

Comment: % is remainder.  Answer details here -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx

Comment: @David: the question is about the meanings of the terms. If you say that the question has no meaning, despite several people understanding it in the way that the questioner intended, then I think you have to be more specific what you mean by the word "mean" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop There are competing meanings for these terms. If the question can specify which of those competing meanings is to be used, then it will be possible to say how they differ.

Answer (score 199):

There is a difference between modulus (Euclidean division) and remainder (C's `%` operator). For example:

`-21` mod `4` is `3` because `-21 + 4 x 6` is `3`.

But `-21` divided by `4` with truncation towards `0` (as C's `/` operator)
gives `-5` with a remainder (C `-21 % 4`) of `-1`.

For positive values, there is no difference between Euclidean and truncating division.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Other_intervals_for_the_remainder - C's choice of truncating the remainder towards `0` ([required since C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)) forces a negative remainder range for negative quotients.  Even in C89, when Euclidean division was allowed by the standard for `/`

> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`.

`(-21/4) * 4  +  (-21%4) == -21`;  C99 and later require `(-5) * 4 + (-1)`, not Euclidean `-6` and `3`.

Comment: tanks, and '%' means either "mod" or "rem" in C ? or meaning of '%' in C depend on implementations ?

Comment: @Jinxiao: in C89 it was implementation-defined: `%` was always the remainder, but it might *also* be the modulus (i.e. always positive), because in C89 integer division was permitted to round towards negative infinity instead of towards 0. So in C89, `-5 / 2` could be `-2` with remainder `-1`, or `-3` with remainder `1`, the implementation just had to document which. C99 removed the flexibility, so now `-5 / 2` is always `-2`.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear what modulus is. There seem to be many different definitions, depending on the context and the language. See the wikipedia article about modulo_operation. In some contexts, it is actually the same as remainder.

Comment: Can someone explain the steps in the first calculation?
How `-21` mod `4` is `3`?
Why the calculation is `-21 + 4 x 6`?

Comment: @OzEdri To get some number mod 4, you add whatever integer multiple of 4 it takes to get a number between 0 and 3. For -21, that integer is 6 because `-21 + 4 x 6` is between 0 and 3.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. By definition (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) the remainder is a positive number, so `-21` divided by `4` gives `-6` with a remainder of `3`

Comment: Yup run the JS for `-21%4` and you'll get `-1`. Seems like the answer-er got them mixed up :)

Comment: @theEpsilon: I would *never* use JS as a trustworthy source. What's `1 + '2'`? `"12"`. What's `1 - '2'` ? `-1`. `-1**2` is a syntax error, though.

Comment: This is wrong.  The modulus is the common residue starting from zero: remainder(|a|,|b|).  This is because `a - b` must be congruent to `a - b%m`.  If `a=2`, `b=-21` and `m=4`, then `a-b = 23` and `23%4 = 3`.  But `3 != |2 - 3|` (the congruency requirement), which is what this answer claims.  This is a contradiction (congruency of a number is equality), and is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for this answer, but then why -21 % -4 in Python (3.10.6) gives -1 instead of -5? Using the idea as you mentioned above, -21 + (-4 * -5) = -1, where -1 is a number between 0 and -4

Comment: @torez233 What would you expect -5 % -4 to give?

Comment: @marcosh: Yes, `-21/4` would have a remainder of 3 in Euclidean division, but this question is about C division and what its `%` operator does, which is *not* Euclidean division, it's a remainder for division with truncation toward zero for the quotient.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Other_intervals_for_the_remainder).  The fact that "remainder" can be used to describe that part of Euclidean division makes this answer a lot less clear than it could be about how integer division works in C, so that should get rephrased.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton - Your edit would have made this wrong as an answer to the question about C's `%` operator; note the phrasing of modulo ... **but** remainder with different numbers.  It makes no sense to still say "but" and then have the same numbers, and not to mention C's truncating division at all.  I made a different edit.  (David; you might want to tidy this up if you think I over-complicated it or made it longer than you wanted.)

Answer (score 71):

> Does '%' mean either "mod" or "rem" in C?

In C, `%` is the **remainder**<sup>1</sup>.

> ..., the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded ... (This is often called "truncation toward zero".) C11dr §6.5.5 6
>
> The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer type.  C11dr §6.5.5 2
>
> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the **remainder** ...  C11dr §6.5.5 5

---

> What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?

C does not define a "mod" nor "modulo" operator/function, such as the integer modulus function used in [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) or [other modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

C defines *remainder*.

Let us compare "remainder" per the `%` operator to the Euclidean "mod".

"Euclidean mod" differs from C's `a%b` operation when `a` is negative.

```
 // a % b, the remainder after an integer division that truncates toward 0.
 7 %  3 -->  1  
 7 % -3 -->  1  
-7 %  3 --> -1  
-7 % -3 --> -1
```

"Mod" or modulo as in Euclidean division.  The result is always 0 or positive.

```
 7 modulo  3 -->  1
 7 modulo -3 -->  1
-7 modulo  3 -->  2
-7 modulo -3 -->  2
```

---

Candidate modulo code:

```
int modulo_Euclidean(int a, int b) {
  int m = a % b;
  if (m < 0) {
    // m += (b < 0) ? -b : b; // avoid this form: it is UB when b == INT_MIN
    m = (b < 0) ? m - b : m + b;
  }
  return m;
}
```

---

Note about floating point: `double fmod(double x, double y)`, even though called "fmod", it is not the same as Euclidean division "mod", but similar to C integer remainder:

> The `fmod` functions compute the floating-point remainder of `x/y`.  C11dr §7.12.10.1 2

```
fmod( 7,  3) -->  1.0
fmod( 7, -3) -->  1.0
fmod(-7,  3) --> -1.0
fmod(-7, -3) --> -1.0
```

---

[Disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguation_(disambiguation)): C also has a similar named function `double modf(double value, double *iptr)` which breaks the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument. This has little to do with the "mod" discussion here except name similarity.

---

[Edit Dec 2020]

For those who want proper functionality in all cases, an improved `modulo_Euclidean()` that 1) detects `mod(x,0)` and 2) a good and no UB result with `modulo_Euclidean2(INT_MIN, -1)`.  Inspired by [4 different implementations of modulo with fully defined behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253799/29485).

```
int modulo_Euclidean2(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) TBD_Code(); // perhaps return -1 to indicate failure?
  if (b == -1) return 0; // This test needed to prevent UB of `INT_MIN % -1`.
  int m = a % b;
  if (m < 0) {
    // m += (b < 0) ? -b : b; // avoid this form: it is UB when b == INT_MIN
    m = (b < 0) ? m - b : m + b;
  }
  return m;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Prior to C99, C's definition of `%` was still the *remainder* from division, yet then `/` allowed negative quotients to round down rather than "truncation toward zero".  See [Why do you get different values for integer division in C89?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29991832). Thus with some pre-C99 compilation, `%` code can act just like the Euclidean division "mod".  The above `modulo_Euclidean()` will work with this alternate old-school remainder too.

[Edit Apr 2024]
No sign [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) will offer any help here.

Comment: To implement Euclidean division and modulo functions in C, see [Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/division-and-modulus-for-computer-scientists/).  It can run faster if you know only your dividend can be negative, but your divisor is always positive: https://godbolt.org/g/63UqJo.  Related: [an x86 asm question asking for non-negative modulo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861023/how-do-i-get-a-positive-modulo-on-a-negative-dividend)

Answer (score 16):

sign of remainder will be same as the divisible and the sign of modulus will be same as divisor.

Remainder is simply the remaining part after the arithmetic division between two integer number whereas Modulus is the sum of remainder and divisor when they are oppositely signed and remaining part after the arithmetic division when remainder and divisor both are of same sign.

**Example of Remainder:**

10 % 3 = 1 [here divisible is 10 which is positively signed so the result will also be positively signed]

-10 % 3 = -1 [here divisible is -10 which is negatively signed so the result will also be negatively signed]

10 % -3 = 1 [here divisible is 10 which is positively signed so the result will also be positively signed]

-10 % -3 = -1 [here divisible is -10 which is negatively signed so the result will also be negatively signed]

**Example of Modulus:**

5 % 3 = 2 [here divisible is 5 which is positively signed so the remainder will also be positively signed and the divisor is also positively signed. As both remainder and divisor are of same sign the result will be same as remainder]

-5 % 3 = 1 [here divisible is -5 which is negatively signed so the remainder will also be negatively signed and the divisor is positively signed. As both remainder and divisor are of opposite sign the result will be sum of remainder and divisor -2 + 3 = 1]

5 % -3 = -1 [here divisible is 5 which is positively signed so the remainder will also be positively signed and the divisor is negatively signed. As both remainder and divisor are of opposite sign the result will be sum of remainder and divisor 2 + -3 = -1]

-5 % -3 = -2 [here divisible is -5 which is negatively signed so the remainder will also be negatively signed and the divisor is also negatively signed. As both remainder and divisor are of same sign the result will be same as remainder]

I hope this will clearly distinguish between remainder and modulus.

Comment: "and the sign of modulus will be same as divisor." and "Modulus is the ..." used here is one of a [number of modulo definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It is certainly not the [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) one.

Comment: I suspect the modulo definition you are using is the [floored division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition) one.

Answer (score 6):

In C and C++ and many languages, `%` is the remainder NOT the modulus operator.

For example in the operation `-21 / 4` the integer part is `-5` and the decimal part is `-.25`. The remainder is the fractional part times the divisor, so our remainder is `-1`. JavaScript uses the remainder operator and confirms this

```js
console.log(-21 % 4 == -1);
```

The modulus operator is like you had a "clock". Imagine a circle with the values 0, 1, 2, and 3 at the 12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6 o'clock, and 9 o'clock positions respectively. Stepping quotient times around the clock clock-wise lands us on the result of our modulus operation, or, in our example with a negative quotient, counter-clockwise, yielding 3.

**Note:** Modulus is always the same sign as the divisor and remainder the same sign as the quotient. Adding the divisor and the remainder when at least one is negative yields the modulus.

Comment: Did you mean that sign of the remainder is always the same sign as the *dividend*?  The quotient of `7 / -3 = -2`, but `7 rem -3 = 1`.

Comment: "remainder the same sign as the quotient" --> No, not in C.  `7/-3` has the quotient `-2` and the `7%-3` has the remainder of `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Modulus, in modular arithmetic as you're referring, is the value left over or remaining value after arithmetic division.  This is commonly known as remainder.  % is formally the remainder operator in C / C++. Example:

```
7 % 3 = 1  // dividend % divisor = remainder
```

What's left for discussion is how to treat negative inputs to this % operation.  Modern C and C++ produce a signed remainder value for this operation where **the sign of the result always matches the dividend input** without regard to the sign of the divisor input.

Answer (score 3):

```
% is a remainder(leftover after dividend / divisor) NOT modulus.
```

You could write your own modulus function using the remainder(%) by the relation

```
  ((n%m)+m)%m

  where `n` is the given number and `m` is the modulus
```

Find below the difference between the remainder and modulus values for the range n = (-7,7) and m = 3

```
n       -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
%(-m)   -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2 -1  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  =>  remainder
% m     -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2 -1  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  =>  remainder
mod m    2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  =>  ((n%m)+m)%m
mod(-m) -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2 -1  0 -2  =>  ((n%m)+m)%m
```

*Tips to remember:*

```
n%(-m)   = +(remainder)
(-n)%(m) = -(remainder)
sign of 'm' doesn't matter

n mod (-m) = -(result)
(-n) mod m = +(result)
sign of 'n' doesn't matter

For +ve 'n' and '%(-m)' or '%m' or 'mod m' gives the same remainder
```

Answer (score -4):

In mathematics the result of the modulo operation is the remainder of the Euclidean division. However, other conventions are possible. Computers and calculators have various ways of storing and representing numbers; thus their definition of the modulo operation depends on the programming language and/or the underlying hardware.

```
 7 modulo  3 -->  1  
 7 modulo -3 --> -2 
-7 modulo  3 -->  2  
-7 modulo -3 --> -1
```

Comment: The [wiki Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) asserts `0 ≤ r < |b|` which means the remainder aka "modulo operation." is always at least 0.  What definition are you using that results in -2 and -1?

Comment: sir, i dont no but i just google 7 modulo -3 --> -2 .and.-7 modulo -3 --> -1 please explain sir why this happened

Comment: Google uses a different definition of modulo (signed modulo?)  than Wiki  Euclidean division (as described by Raymond T. Boute).  [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) discusses the differences more.  Moral of the story: `a%b` and `a modulo b` have the same meaning when `a,b` are positive.  C99 defines `%` precisely with negative values.  C calls this "remainder'.  "Modulo" has various definitions in the world concerning negative values.  C spec only uses "modulo" in the context of positive numbers.