# How does JavaScript handle modulo?

Tags: javascript, modulo

I was wondering how JavaScript handles modulo. For example, what would JavaScript evaluate `47 % 8` as? I can’t seem to find any documentation on it, and my skills on modulo aren’t the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as every language handles modulo: The remainder of `X / Y`.

```
47 % 8 == 7
```

Also if you use a browser like Firefox + Firebug, Safari, Chrome, or even IE8+ you could test such an operation as quickly as hitting F12.

Comment: Note that *some* languages (notably C) treat `%` as a *remainder* operator rather than a *modulo* operator... http://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/3651800

Comment: This answer is incorrect in that modulo is not the same as remainder, JavaScript does indeed use `%` for remainder not modulo. This is not exactly the same as every other language: many do in fact use `%` for modulo

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's modulo operator returns a negative number when given a negative number as input (on the left side).

```js
14 % 5 // 4
15 % 5 // 0
-15 % 5 // -0
-14 % 5 // -4
```

(Note: negative zero is a distinct value in JavaScript and other languages with IEEE floats, but `-0 === 0` so you usually don't have to worry about it.)

If you want a number that is always between 0 and a positive number that you specify, you can define a function like so:

```js
function mod(n, m) {
    return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}
```

```js
mod(14, 5) // 4
mod(15, 5) // 4
mod(-15, 5) // 0
mod(-14, 5) // 1
```

[image: comparison of remainder and modulo]

Answer (score 0):

Modulo should behave like you expect. I expect.

```
47 % 8 == 7
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hektk/)

Answer (score 0):

TO better understand modulo here is how its built;

```
function modulo(num1, num2) {
    if (typeof num1 != "number" || typeof num2 != "number"){
      return NaN
    }
    var num1isneg=false
     if (num1.toString().includes("-")){
      num1isneg=true
    }
      num1=parseFloat(num1.toString().replace("-",""))
      var leftover =parseFloat( ( parseFloat(num1/num2) - parseInt(num1/num2)) *num2)
      console.log(leftover)
            if (num1isneg){
              var z = leftover.toString().split("")
              z= ["-", ...z]
              leftover = parseFloat(z.join(""))
            }
            return leftover
}
```