# What is the meaning of the percent character in this code?

Tags: c, int

In this case, what does the percentage refers to?

```
int myInt = 27 % 10;  
myInt = 7;
```

What does the `%` mean in this code?

Comment: It's the modulus operator.

Comment: `%` is remainder operator, @MattBall not modulus

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan there's a difference?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Euh, do you speak English?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan _Remainder_ not _rememder/remember_

Comment: @MattBall yes, there is...

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Namely what?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard : thanks!  H2CO3 my English is poor, but point is its not modulus but remainder.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan But they are the same...

Comment: @MattBall [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder” ？](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder) and [What's the difference? Remainder vs Modulus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/05/what-s-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus.aspx)

Comment: @H2CO3 +1 to your comment :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks! Now I'm just waiting for the explanation of iamnotmaynard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not putting any effort in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

% means remainder, when 27 is divided by 10 leaves a remainder 7

```
EDIT:
```

My 2 cents about all the discussion about difference between modulo & remainder

Take a % b

```
1. When both +ve, Modulo & Remainder are one and the same
2. When a is -ve, they are not the same
```

For example;

a = -10, b = 3

Remainder of -10 % 3  = -1

for Modulo, add a greater multiple of 3 to your 'a' and calculate the remainder.

-10 + 12 = 2

2 % 3 = 2 is your answer

Answer (score 3):

the `%` is modulus operator, not percentage.  For percentage, you just do regular math.  50% is to multiply by .5... etc.

For future reference, the objective c mathematical operations are documented many places, [including here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Objective-C_Arithmetic_Operators).

Note the `%` is called ["Modulo" operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a operator to find the remainder of a division.

Answer (score 0):

The "%" in this code is called the modulus operator. This causes the processor to perform a division operation, and it returns the remainder of the division.

For example:

- 8 % 10 = 8
- 5 % 4 = 1