# Why does ~-1 equal 0 and ~1 equal -2?

Tags: javascript, operators, bitwise-operators, ecmascript-5

According to subsection [11.4.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8) of the ECMAScript 5.1 standard:

> The production *UnaryExpression* : ~ *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `expr` be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. Let `oldValue` be `ToInt32(GetValue(expr))`.
> 3. Return the result of applying bitwise complement to `oldValue`. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

The `~` operator will invoke the internal method `ToInt32`. In my understanding `ToInt32(1)` and `ToInt32(-1)` will return the same value 1 , but why does `~-1` equal 0 and `~1` equal -2?

Now my question is why `ToInt32(-1)` equals -1?
subsection [9.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) of the ECMAScript 5.1 standard:

> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts its argument to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer values 
>       in the range −2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive. This abstract operation functions as
>       follows:
>
> 1. Let number be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.
> 3. Let posInt be sign(number) * floor(abs(number)).
> 4. Let int32bit be posInt modulo 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value k of Number
>          type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude such that the mathematical
>          difference of posInt and k is mathematically an integer multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.
> 5. If int32bit is greater than or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>, return int32bit − 2<sup>32</sup>, otherwise
>          return int32bit.

when the argument is -1,according to 9.5,
in step 1
number will still be -1,
skip step2
in step 3
posInt will be -1
in step 4
int32bit  will be 1
in step 5 it will return 1

which step is wrong?

Comment: ToIn32(-1) should yield -1 according to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5

Comment: Your understanding is wrong and  was corrected in your previous question... (more specifically, in my answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the result of 'x modulo y'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256823/what-is-the-result-of-x-modulo-y)

Comment: Found this helpful when looking up information about tilde. http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/. Basically `~x === -(x + 1)`

Answer (score 17):

The `-1` in 32-bit integer

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

So `~-1` will be

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Which is zero.

The `1` in 32-bit integer

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

So `~1` will be

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

Which is `-2`.

You should read about [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) to understand the display of negative integer in binary-base.

Comment: Thank you for showing my error, I just miss typing this value. It is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the idea that `ToInt32(-1)` evaluates to 1? It evaluates to -1, which in 32-bit, two's complement binary representation, is all bits set to 1. When you apply the `~` operator, every bit then becomes 0, which is the representation of 0 in 32-bit, two's complement binary.

The representation of 1 is all bits 0 except for bit 0. When the bits are inverted, the result is all bits 1 except for bit 0. This happens to be the two's complement representation of -2. (To see this, just subtract 1 from the two's complement representation of -1.)

Answer (score 0):

- `ToInt32(1)` will return `1`
- `ToInt32(-1)` will return `-1`
- `-1` is represented as a signed 32-bit integer by having all 32 bits set. The bitwise complement of that is all bits clear, thus `~-1` yields `0`
- `1` is represented as a signed 32-bit integer by having all bits clear except the bottom bit. The bitwise complement of that has all bits set except the bottom bit, which is the signed 32-bit integer representation of the value `-2`. Thus, `~1` yields `-2`