# New to programming: Can someone give me a limple explanation to looping over a list using the %len

Tags: python, list, loops

I have searched for a really basic explanation on what the %len does when trying to loop over a list.

This is an example of the code. What I am trying to do it to print each of the letters in the list giving a starting point. In this example I have just set it to 0. The idea is that I am going to create a cypher shift program. I know loads of people have given answers to the cypher but I just don't understand what the %len does and what I am doing that it wont work in this example.

Thanks a million in advance!

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz")


count = 0


for i in range (100):
    print (alphabet[i]%len(alphabet))
```

Comment: % is modulo or string formatting, this is distinct from len() which will give you the length of a list for example.

Comment: First of all I can see that print alphabet[i] with i being greater than 25 will produce an index out of range error. So you could change the print statement to print(alphabet[i % len(alphabet)]) which in turn will recursively print the letter of the alphabet 4 times

Answer (score 2):

It is a [remainder operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), sometimes (incorrectly) also called "modulo operator".

`i` your case will grow beyond the size of your string. By calculating the remainder of `i` and the maximum value `len(alphabet)` it will automatically restart at 0:

```
print 25 % 26 # 25
print 26 % 26 # 0
print 27 % 26 # 1
print 28 % 26 # 2
```

Comment: Note % is a remainder, *not* a mod operator.

Comment: To my knowledge the modulo operator calulates the remainder.

Comment: yes for +ve number, but not for negative you would like to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder)

Comment: hmm  I got a better blog post: here [MODULUS AND REMAINDER ARE NOT THE SAME](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/modulus-remainder)

Comment: @NilsWerner: The `%` operator in Python is not the same as the `%` in some other languages like C and Java. In Python it *is* [the modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), not a remainder operator. `-1 % 4 == 3`, not `-1`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it stands doesn't work, I get a `TypeError`. I think what you are trying to do is:

```
for i in range(100):
    print(alphabet[i % len(alphabet)])
```

Here the benefit of `%` is that `x % c` gives you the remainder after `x` is divided by `c`, so ensures that the index is always within the bounds of your list.

Comment: And here % is used as mod operation.  Nice  guess.

Comment: My guess was better than Python's, which was that the OP was trying to use `%` string formatting on a single character...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you are trying to achieve is to iterate recursively through the alphabet list 4 times (hence 100 = 25*4) although it should be 104 instead of 100

As it is currently your code will produce a list index our of range error so you should consider changing it to:

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

for i in range(104):

    print (alphabet[i % len(alphabet)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much people, you are stars! Its really simple now you explain it! I couldnt find anywhere that would explain it simply!

Comment: No problem mate anytime :) It is nice to see people who are appreciating our effort in trying to help them and don't just ignore us ^^