# Is there a modulus (not remainder) function / operation?

Tags: rust, modulo

In Rust (like most programming languages), the `%` operator performs the *remainder* operation, not the *modulus* operation. These [operations have different results for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/155423):

```
-21 modulus 4 => 3
-21 remainder 4 => -1
```

```
println!("{}", -21 % 4); // -1
```

However, I **want** the modulus.

I found a workaround `((a % b) + b) % b`, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already a function for that!

Comment: Any reason to use the term `modulus` instead of `modulo` (which is more common AFAICS).

Comment: They might have studied somewhere where the term modulus is used, not knowing that different institutions tend to differ in vocabulary.

Comment: For powers of two, you can do something like -21 & (4 - 1), granted it's an integer.

Answer (score 122):

[RFC 2196](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2169-euclidean-modulo.md) adds a couple of integer methods related to euclidian division. Specifically, the `rem_euclid` method ([example link for `i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.rem_euclid)) is what you are searching for:

```rust
println!("{}", -1i32 % 4);                // -1
println!("{}", (-21i32).rem_euclid(4));   // 3
```

This method is available in `rustc 1.38.0` (released on 2019-09-27) and above.

Comment: They are also implemented for unsigned variants, although it is not possible to figure out what they do from that documentation. I would also mention `div_euclid()` for completeness. But this should be the selected answer anyway.

Comment: @nert  when you see `int_impl!` you can go to this file and see the actual implementation: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/81799cd8fd841e23b52876ae5e22faeb3ad04eb5/library/core/src/num/int_macros.rs#L672-L696

Comment: such a misnomer. remainder should be modulos and modulos remainder.

Answer (score 43):

> Is there a modulus (not remainder!) function / operation in Rust?

As far as I can tell, there is no *modular arithmetic* function.

This also happens in C, where it is common to use the workaround you mentioned: `((a % b) + b) % b`.

In C, C++, D, C#, F# and Java, `%` is in fact the remainder. In Perl, Python or Ruby, `%` is the modulus.

Language developers don't always go the "correct mathematical way", so computer languages might seem weird from the strict mathematician view. The thing is that both modulus and remainder, are correct for different uses.

Modulus is more mathematical if you like, while the remainder (in the C-family) is consistent with common integer division satisfying: `(a / b) * b + a % b = a`; this is adopted from old Fortran. So `%` is better called the remainder, and I suppose Rust is being consistent with C.

You are not the first to note this:

- [No modulo operator?](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13909)
- [Remainder is not modulus, but int::rem() uses the mod operator.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/4565) .

Comment: I, as a C/C++ programmer, am embarrassed that I didn't know that `%` works in C that way, too...

Comment: Isn't this a gap in Rust?

Comment: Well, as you expect, this is not something mathematicians enjoy. And i would not say it is a gap, for all this family of languages `%` is just the remainder.

Comment: I'll go with `%` being the remainder, but not having support for modulus sucks...

Comment: @JosEduSol As I write this, the answer above shows `(a % b) + b` as a way to calculate the modulus, but I'm pretty sure what you meant to write is this: `((a % b) + b) % b`.

Comment: `(a / b) * b + a mod b = a` is satisfied if `/` rounds toward -∞.

Comment: It has been added now, see next comment.

Answer (score 10):

No, Rust doesn't have a built in modulus, see [this discussion](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-April/003683.html) for some reasons why.

Here's an example that might be handy:

```
///
/// Modulo that handles negative numbers, works the same as Python's `%`.
///
/// eg: `(a + b).modulo(c)`
///
pub trait ModuloSignedExt {
    fn modulo(&self, n: Self) -> Self;
}
macro_rules! modulo_signed_ext_impl {
    ($($t:ty)*) => ($(
        impl ModuloSignedExt for $t {
            #[inline]
            fn modulo(&self, n: Self) -> Self {
                (self % n + n) % n
            }
        }
    )*)
}
modulo_signed_ext_impl! { i8 i16 i32 i64 }
```

Comment: Would `modulo_signed_ext_impl! { i8 i16 i32 i64 isize u8 u16 u32 u64 usize }` be better?

Answer (score -4):

From the other answers I constructed:

```
fn n_mod_m <T: std::ops::Rem<Output = T> + std::ops::Add<Output = T> + Copy>
  (n: T, m: T) -> T {
    ((n % m) + m) % m
}

assert_eq!(n_mod_m(-21, 4), 3);
```

Comment: If you're going to use that on integers, how is it better than the built-in [`rem_euclid` mentioned in Lukas Kalbertodt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342011/2733851)?

Comment: I find this explicit function easier to mentally parse than the opaque .rem_euclid()