# Non-exhaustive patterns - Rust match expressions

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have an issue with the following Rust code:

```
pub fn median(v: &Vec<i32>) -> f32 {
    let len = v.len();
    match len % 2 {
        0 => (v[len / 2 - 1] + v[len / 2]) as f32 / 2 as f32,
        1 => v[(len - 1) / 2] as f32,
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile due to a 'Non exhaustive patterns' error.
Why is that? What does the % operator return?

Comment: `len % 2 == 0` and match with true and false

Comment: You could aslo do this, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=156dcf0fc428ec74aadf546d98d5c5e0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use `_` instead of `1`:

```
match len % 2 {
    0 => (v[len / 2 - 1] + v[len / 2]) as f32 / 2 as f32,
    _ => v[(len - 1) / 2] as f32,
}
```

Because `len` is odd and non-negative in the second branch, `(len - 1) / 2` is the same as `len / 2`. I would simplify it like this:

```
let mid = v.len() / 2;
match v.len() % 2 {
    0 => (v[mid - 1] + v[mid]) as f32 / 2.0,
    _ => v[mid] as f32,
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The compiler is not smart enough to figure out that the result of `len % 2` can only ever be `0` or `1`. It demands a match arm for cases where the result is some other value. You can solve this by explicitly saying that those cases are impossible:

```
match len % 2 {
    0 => (v[len / 2 - 1] + v[len / 2]) as f32 / 2 as f32,
    1 => v[(len - 1) / 2] as f32,
    _ => unreachable!()
}
```

The `_` will match any other value not previously mentioned. The [`unreachable!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) tells the compiler "this code will never execute", but cause a `panic!()` just in case it does in fact execute. That way, the program is *correct* all the time at practically no cost.

Future versions of the compiler might figure out that the values `2..` or not possible.

The `%` is the [`remainder operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210357/is-there-a-modulus-not-remainder-function-operation) (not to be cofused with the `mod`-operator).

Comment: > The compiler is not smart enough to figure out that the result of len % 2 can only ever be 0 or 1.  

  
Yes, it is. But the type system requires that match arms be exhaustive over the whole type, even when the compiler can figure out that it's not necessary.

Comment: As a quick sidenote: In release mode, the compiler can detect, that only `0` and `1` is possible and therefore eleminate the `_` branch completly. https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PVgltd