# Program isn't registering negative numbers when I take %

Tags: java, modulus

I'm writing a program that takes the mod of a integer and proceeds to do some further math, but for some reason it's not registering negative numbers in the mod operator.

For example:

Let's say the test class inputs n = -90

```
public static double mod(int n) {
    double mod = (n % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    return mod;
}
```

The actual `(n % 360)` is returning -90 instead of 270 and I can't figure out why.

However my code works for positive numbers.

Comment: `%` isn't a *mod* operator. Rather it's a *remainder* operator, hence the reason for your question, one with duplicates on this site, I'm sure (but haven't found yet).

Comment: Found a dup, closed.

Comment: [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder)