# How do I get a positive modulo on a negative dividend

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-division

I am trying to get a modulo-n (0 < n) in the range `[0 ... n-1]`.

The instruction [`idiv n`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) divides EDX:EAX (64 bits) by n, and leaves
EAX=quotient, EDX=remainder.  (`n` is a register in my code)

My problem is that when the content of EDX:EAX is negative, I get a negative result in EDX.

The simplest solution I found was:

```
cdq            ; extend EAX sign bit to EDX
idiv n         ; edx = (possibly neg.) remainder
add edx, n
mov eax, edx   ; eax = remainder + n
cdq
idiv n         ; edx = positive remainder
```

Is there a cleaner/easier/quicker way to get the positive remainder?

Comment: It's called remainder. Quotient is the result of division.

Comment: Now I see you didn't specify `n` to be positive explicitly, I deducted that one from *"edx:eax is negative => negative remainder"*, which can happen only for positive `n`. ("non-negative" as well, because `n==0` will fail sooner :) ).

Comment: @Ped7g, Thanks for your comments. I will edit and change 'quotient' to 'remainder'. About n, I did mention that 0 < n.

Answer (score 4):

-5 mod *3* = **-2** (remainder, -1 quotient)

patched remainder: **-2** + 3 = **+1**, that's what you want, right?

Quotient is then -1 - 1 = -2.

Verification: -2 * *3* + **+1** = -5

```
cdq            ; extend EAX sign bit to EDX
idiv n         ; edx = (possibly neg.) remainder
mov eax, edx   ; eax = copy of remainder
add edx, n     ; negative remainder modified to positive one (for --quotient)
               ; when going from negative to positive, CF will be set (unsigned overflow)
cmovc eax,edx  ; when CF, load eax with modified remainder
; eax = to-be-positive-adjusted remainder
```

I didn't verify it in debugger, and I merely woke up, so test it first.

Comment: Yeah, looks right for positive divisors at least.  Wrapping around from negative to positive sets CF.  (That's *not* signed overflow though, so I'd suggest calling it "wraparound" instead of `(overflow)` to avoid confusion.)

Comment: I think this breaks for large positive remainders, though:  if `n + remainder` carries, then you'll get `n + remainder` instead of a positive remainder.

Comment: @PeterCordes been thinking about it.. He's using `idiv`, so `n` is signed 32b. Then MAX_N = `0x7F...FF` . Max remainder is `0x7F...FE`. `0x7F...FF` + `0x7F...FE` = `0xFF...FD`, **CF = 0**. So as long as `n` is signed and positive, it should work correctly.  EDIT: and I'm not sure about that "wraparound" wording either, the `add edx,n` does produce classic unsigned `add` overflow, when you look at it without signed context. I added at least "unsigned" to it, but "overflow" feels right for me in this case? Depends probably how you read the code in mind, if you do negative+n or uint+n?

Comment: Ahh, yes good point.  I agree, `MAX_INT + MAX_INT` doesn't carry, and the OP has said that the divisor is non-negative, so there's no problem.

Comment: Anyway, at least you made me to think about it, I was simply ignoring it before, because I found it very unlikely the divisors are large.. but better to *know* for sure. :) Thanks.

Comment: Turns out we can get clang to emit this asm given the right C input (see my answer).  gcc still wants to use a CMP instead of reading CF from the ADD.  Wouldn't have been worth a whole answer except that I also found an interesting paper, and what this kind of modulo is called mathematically.

Answer (score 4):

The kind of division that produces a non-negative modulo is called [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).

For C implementations and more background, see [Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/division-and-modulus-for-computer-scientists/).  (also related: [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder/20638659#20638659)).

This is a special case, where we know the divisor is positive, which allows the faster implementation suggested by Ped7g.  It's probably optimal or at least close to it.

**Interestingly, we can write it in C in a way that compiles to the same asm as Ped7g's hand-written version** (or close to it, depending on gcc vs. clang).  See it [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Climits.h%3E%0A%0A//+Euclidean+(0..+%7Cn-1%7C)+modulo%0A//+from+https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/division-and-modulus-for-computer-scientists/%0A%0A//+https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861023/how-do-i-get-a-positive-modulo-on-a-negative-dividend%0A//+uses+unsigned+carry+to+detect+when+a+negative+2!'s+complement+integer+wrapped+to+non-negative%0A//+Compiles+to+about+the+same+asm+as+Ped7g!'s+hand-written+asm%0Along+modE_positive_divisor_2s_complement(+long+D,+long+d+)%0A%7B%0A++long+r+%3D+D%25d%3B%0A%0A++unsigned+long+tmp+%3D+(unsigned+long)r+%2B+(unsigned+long)d%3B%0A++//+detect+carry+by+looking+for+unsigned+wraparound:%0A++//+that+means+remainder+was+negative+(not+zero),+so+adding+the+(non-negative)+divisor+is+what+we+need%0A++r+%3D+(tmp+%3C+(unsigned+long)r)+%3F+(long)tmp+:+r%3B%0A%0A++return+r%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Along+modE_orig(+long+D,+long+d+)+%7B%0A++long+r+%3D+D%25d%3B%0A++if+(r+%3C+0)+%7B%0A++++//+used+%3E%3D+in+case+the+compiler+can+prove+that+d+is+non-negative+more+easily+than+positive%0A++++if+(d+%3E%3D+0)+r+%3D+r+%2B+d%3B%0A++++else+r+%3D+r+-+d%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+r%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Along+modE_positive_divisor(+long+D,+long+d+)+%7B%0A++//+doesn!'t+seem+to+help+clang%0A++if+(d+%3C%3D+0)%0A++++__builtin_unreachable()%3B%0A%0A++//+but+this+does+(clang+still+does+the+AND,+though)%0A++d+%26%3D+LONG_MAX%3B%0A++%0A++long+r+%3D+D%25d%3B%0A++if+(r+%3C+0)+%7B%0A++++//+optimizes+to+r+%2B%3D+d%0A++++if+(d+%3E%3D+0)+r+%3D+r+%2B+d%3B%0A++++else+r+%3D+r+-+d%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+r%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861023/how-do-i-get-a-positive-modulo-on-a-negative-dividend
// uses unsigned carry to detect when a negative 2's complement integer wrapped to non-negative
long modE_positive_divisor_2s_complement( long D, long d )
{
  long r = D%d;

  unsigned long tmp = (unsigned long)r + (unsigned long)d;
  // detect carry by looking for unsigned wraparound:
  // that means remainder was negative (not zero), so adding the (non-negative) divisor is what we need
  r = (tmp < (unsigned long)r) ? (long)tmp : r;

  return r;
}
```

With clang3.9 -O3, we get:

```
    mov     rax, rdi
    cqo
    idiv    rsi
    add     rsi, rdx
    cmovae  rsi, rdx
    mov     rax, rsi
    ret
```

gcc6.2 uses an extra CMP before the CMOV :(

On Godbolt, I included the original general-case C function and a version that tells the compiler to assume positive `d` (using `__builtin_unreachable()`).  For the latter, gcc does about as well as with this, using a `test rdx,rdx` / `cmovs` to do the conditional add.

It works identically for 32-bit vs. 64-bit `long` (with EAX instead of RAX, etc.), so use `int32_t` if you care about performance and don't need 64-bit integers.  (`idiv r64` is much slower than `idiv r32`).