# Using the % Symbol In c#

Tags: c#

I know the % is a symbol that can't be used by itself but I'm trying to make a number with a percent.

For example:

```
 DeliveryGoal = 85%;
```

But Visual Studio tells me that this is an "invalid expression term". 
Is it a string or a type? Is there a conversion that I have to do? Also what declaration would percent symbols fall under? I'm using c#.

I'm not sure if I'm being specific but I'm not trying to get the remainder but rather the symbol itself to display next to that 85.

Comment: Have you Googled anything?

Comment: Yes, I phrased the question "declaring % symbol in c#". I also reworded and click on links but they don't point me to something directly.

Comment: "I know the % is a symbol that can be used by itself" - nope, it's only the remainder operator...

Comment: @Crusader88 OK, then start reading basic c# docs...

Comment: If you looked up [what the percentage symbol does in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx), you'll see that it's only a modulus operator. To decalre a percentage, like 85%, you would enter that in like `0.85`, or `85.0 / 100.0`.

Comment: That is an invalid expression because `%` or *modulo* is just "return the remainder of the left side divided by the right side." It needs both, if you want a percent, well, .85 just happens to be a percentage representing what you want.

Comment: % is a Multiplicative operator, you cannot re-declare it. Try to add it as a symbol to string: $"{value} %"

Comment: @MarkBenovsky what? *% is a Multiplicative operator,* ?

Comment: What is the data type of DeliveryGoal and what do you want to do with it? I would think assigning the "%" would be irrelevant if you are using that like an integer, you only need to show the "% symbol" when you display it ... in that case what you are trying to do is unnecessary in the assignment.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6a71f45d.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: @MarkBenovsky you can *overload* it, but it is a binary operator.

Comment: I'm Sorry Guys, I'm not sure if I'm not being specific but I'm not trying to get the remainder but rather the symbol itself to display next to that 85.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky It may be a multiplicative operator (as in it relates somehow to multiplication) but calling it such is incredibly confusing as it sounds like you are calling it the multiplication operator.

Comment: oops. so `DeliveryGoal` is a string meant for output/display? edit that into the question.

Comment: @dlatikay Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Crusader88: Don't worry about the downvote brigade, it is harsher than it needs to be.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky thanks a lot for enlarging my vocabulary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DeliveryGoal` is a string, then just declare it as a string literal: `"88%"`

If it is a double, then parse the `double` and add the symbol:

```
string percent = (val * 100).ToString() + "%";
```

Alternatively, you can have the `ToString` method format the `double` for you:

```
string percent = val.ToString("P");
```

See the MSDN page on [`double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx) for more formatting options.

Comment: I think what you posted is what I'm looking for, but I have to mess around with it a little to get what I need for the program I'm working on.

Comment: @Crusader88 If you post some more details on how your program uses `DeliveryGoal`, we can write more specific answers to your question.

Comment: I'm very new to stack. I will do my best. I'm at work and they block a lot of sites. I cant copy and paste code into here, and a website like pastebin is blocked...

Comment: Is there a way I can send you some code? Posing my question with it being visual would be best I think to help answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Put your value in quotes `"85%"` to get C# to allow it. You should always do that for non-numbers meant for display.

For those trying to get 85% the number:

C# defines `%` as a binary operator similar to `*` that performs the remainder which is the leftover in division (negative numbers are weird though so watch out for them).

There is no concept of a number `85%` since that is syntactically `85 % ___` where the underscore is an unspecified value.

If you want to numerically represent `85%` you should instead write `0.85` or `85.0 / 100` if you want the percentage. (Note that you cannot do `85 / 100` since that is `0` due to integer division).

Comment: Remainder and modulus aren't the same operation.  They're similar, and related, but not the same.  % is the remainder operator, not the modulus operator.

Comment: @Servy false. `%` *is* the modulus operator.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Actually, he may be right. Formally, MSDN refers to `%` as the modulus operator, but according to [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder), the operator actually behaves as a remainder operation, not a modulus operation. (`int i = -21 % 4;` will result in `-1`.)

Comment: it may be [called modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), but what it does is to [compute the remainder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Comment: Just going to replace with remainder since the nuance is pointless in this case and that is the more commonly understood phrasing. Quick searching shows there isn't a consensus as to which is which honestly.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is used for [modulus expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx). It:

> Divides the value of one expression by the value of another, and returns the remainder.

If you want to apply a percentage of a number, use a multiplication.

```
float DeliveryGoal = 0.85;
float totalCommands = 100; // Or whatever value
float totalDelivery = 80; // Or whatever value
if(totalDelivery /  totalCommands > DeliveryGoal)
    // Objective is reached
```

Comment: The link is to the JScript documentation, not C#.

Comment: @mikez my bad, just changed the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To represent a percentage, you would of course divide by 100 when setting the value.

```
float myPercentage = 0.85;
```

Note that **numeric variables in and of themselves do not contain any formatting information**.  A float is just a binary representation of the pure number, and as you (should) know 85% and 0.85 are equal and equivalent.

To display it with a % sign, you would use `ToString()` and the "p" [format code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine(myPercentage.ToString("p"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%` outside of a string is treated as an operator.

To get the percentage to display exactly like `85%`, you want to use a string to include `%`.

`DeliveryGoal = "85%";`