# How modulus operation works in C++?

Tags: c++, modulus

Why do I get this output: 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1  after running the code below? Doesn't the modulus operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
for (int i=0; i< 10; ++i)
cout << i % 4 << " ";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how modulus works.

Comment: **−1** What research did you do before asking?

Comment: Googled it.....

Comment: And what would you expect the output to be? Why do you think the output you're getting is not the remainder?

Comment: I still don't understand How they explained it here.. Should 't I have the output: 0 25 50 75 0 25 50 75 0... And so on till i is 10? Because: 0/4=0; 1/4= 0,25; 2/4=0.50...and so on..

Comment: @Jack: This is integer arithmetic, in particular it's [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). In C++, as opposed to the definition in Mathworld, and as opposed to the Python language's integer division, in C++ integer division rounds towards zero.

Comment: So 0.25 round to zero should be zero, right? 0,50 rounded to zero should be also zero.. So the first 3 digits as output from the code should be : 0 0 0 , not 0 1 2

Comment: Now i get it, but only from 5... 5: 4*1 = 4 so 5-4=1 .. Also for 6: 4*1= 4 and 6-4 = 2 and so on.. That's the logic I find. But only when the left term is higher than 4...

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Your problem is not related to C++ or programming. It is related to math. You don't know what the math term "remainder" means. Look it up.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is correct. '%' mean  "reminder". The % operator is *remainder operator*. The `A % B` operator actually answer the question “If I divided A by B using integer arithmetic, what would the remainder be?”

> dividend = quotient * divisor + remainder

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
.....
etc..
```

For negative number...

```
   1 % (-4) = 1
(-2) % 4    = -2
(-3) % (-4) = -3
```

> With a remainder operator, the sign of the result is the same as the sign of the dividend

you can read more at [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how modulus works. The output is correct.

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
...
```

Take the number, remove as many 4's as you can. Whatever is left over is the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus operator returns the **remainder** after dividing the first number with the second one.

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
6 % 4 = 2
7 % 4 = 3
8 % 4 = 0
9 % 4 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It does.
0 / 4 = 0 remainder 0
1 / 4 = 0 remainder 1
and so on.