# Unexpected modulo behavior with long integers

Tags: c++, long-integer, modulo

The modulo `%` operator of C++ behaves strangely when operands are `(un)signed` or `long`.

Why would `mod(signed int, unsigned int)` and `mod(signed long long int, unsigned long long int)` produce different results? How do I do if I want the *correct* one (here: 11183)?

**Note:** If I follow my algorithm, I should call `uint64_t mod(int64_t, uint64_t)`.

```
// Tip: 11183 is the "correct" expected result.

(                   int)(-3365) % (                   int)(15156) = -3365
(  signed           int)(-3365) % (  signed           int)(15156) = -3365
(unsigned           int)(-3365) % (unsigned           int)(15156) = 11183
(  signed           int)(-3365) % (unsigned           int)(15156) = 11183
(unsigned           int)(-3365) % (  signed           int)(15156) = 11183

(              long int)(-3365) % (              long int)(15156) = -3365
(  signed      long int)(-3365) % (  signed      long int)(15156) = -3365
(unsigned      long int)(-3365) % (unsigned      long int)(15156) = 2555
(  signed      long int)(-3365) % (unsigned      long int)(15156) = 2555
(unsigned      long int)(-3365) % (  signed      long int)(15156) = 2555

(         long long int)(-3365) % (         long long int)(15156) = -3365
(  signed long long int)(-3365) % (  signed long long int)(15156) = -3365
(unsigned long long int)(-3365) % (unsigned long long int)(15156) = 2555
(  signed long long int)(-3365) % (unsigned long long int)(15156) = 2555
(unsigned long long int)(-3365) % (  signed long long int)(15156) = 2555

(          int_fast16_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast16_t)(15156) = -3365
(         uint_fast16_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast16_t)(15156) = 2555
(          int_fast16_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast16_t)(15156) = 2555
(         uint_fast16_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast16_t)(15156) = 2555

(          int_fast32_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast32_t)(15156) = -3365
(         uint_fast32_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast32_t)(15156) = 2555
(          int_fast32_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast32_t)(15156) = 2555
(         uint_fast32_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast32_t)(15156) = 2555

(          int_fast64_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast64_t)(15156) = -3365
(         uint_fast64_t)(-3365) % (          int_fast64_t)(15156) = 2555
(          int_fast64_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast64_t)(15156) = 2555
(         uint_fast64_t)(-3365) % (         uint_fast64_t)(15156) = 2555
```

PS: More information about my system:

Linux pc-gi-446 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Why don't you investigate what is the value of `(uint64_t) -3365`?  Let's call it `val`; then are you still surprised what happens when you calculate `val % 15156`?

Comment: Unsigned types do not represent negative values. When a negative integer is converted to an unsigned type, a modulo operation happens to produce a non-negative value in the range of that unsigned type.  When you then apply your own modulo, that's a second modulo on top of that one.   The modulo operation which is applied to the original value uses a modulus of `(1 + MAX)` where `MAX` is the highest value of that unsigned type.  For instance `(unsigned int) -3` causes the `-3` to be reduced to the smallest positive value modulo `ULONG_MAX` + 1, resulting in the value `ULONG_MAX - 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
unsigned int x = -3365; printf("%u", x);
```

It won't print "3365", but will print the max value of an unsigned int minus 3365 + 1, i.e. `UINT_MAX-3365+1`, which is `4294963931`.

So `(unsigned int)(-3365) % (unsigned int)(15156)` is the same as `unsigned int z = 4294963931 % 15156; printf("%u\n", z)` and gives `11183`.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is not *modulo*.

See also [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359), a C answer that applies here too.

---

In C++, `%` is the *remainder* of a division.  `-3365/15156` --> 0.  The remainder of the division is -3365.

```
(int)(-3365) % (int)(15156) = -3365
```

---

The following appears wrong at first, yet due to conversion to *unsigned* math, it is correct

```
(unsigned long int)(-3365) % (unsigned long int)(15156) = 2555
(ULONG_MAX + 1 -3365) % 15156 = 2555
```

Comment: Why would mod(signed int, unsigned int) and mod(signed long long int, unsigned long long int) produce different results?

Comment: @Odepax Step 1: With `signed int %  unsigned int` both arguments are converted to `unsigned` before the `%` occurs. With `signed long long %  unsigned long long` both arguments are converted to `unsigned long long` before the `%` occurs.  Is there any question of why that happens?  Step 2: what values are those first arguments changed to?