# My C program stops when iteration variable reaches 2100 why?

Tags: c, long-integer

I have written a simple C code like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long iteration = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        iteration += 10;
        
        if(iteration % 100000000 == 0)
        {
            printf("Iteration %ld\n", iteration / 1000000);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the `iteration` reaches to 2100, the program stops (doesn't print anything). It seems that the `iteration` is considered as `int` by the compiler (GNU gcc), but I defined it as `long`. What is the problem?

2100 * 1000000 = 2100000000 (2.1 billions) and it is `int` overflow but my variable has been defined as `long`.

Comment: Your compiler should be generating a few warnings for this. Read them.

Comment: `long` != `long long`.

Comment: Hint: print `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: Will it work if you use long long or unsigned long? I'm not sure if it is the same with C, but in C# and C++, long has the same range as int.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019

Comment: @ GSerg: many thanks it's the answer. but why doesn't "long iteration" work ? it's 8 bytes length

Comment: many thanks. "long long iteration" works. but why doesn't "long iteration" work? long is 8 bytes length

Comment: `it's 8 bytes length` - is it though? Have you verified, and have you visited the links?

Comment: @Gserg: here is the link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Comment: @abcdef Not a very good one then. Please see the ones at the top of the question instead.

Comment: please read [signed values in modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686864/unexpected-modulo-behavior-with-long-integer)

Comment: The code you posted will hit the `printf` even if `iteration` is 32 bits.

Comment: Also referring to @3Dave 's comment - always seek extra warning from your compiler , use flags such as : `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconvert`