# Mixed type arithmetics and overflow in C

Tags: c, types, casting, overflow

I have a function which converts counter value using a factor and returns the result as unsigned long. I need to handle possible overflow.

IntVars.Counter_ui32:

- unsigned long with range 2^32 and max value 2^32-1 -> 4294967295

IntVars.Factor_fl32 (and Result local variable)

- float 32 bits with max value -> ~3,4E+38
- is calculated in another function which assures that the factor will never be negative

In general I don't mind if the result overflows the type unsigned long as long as the value is valid and the remainder of unsigned long is returned. For this reason I assume I need to implement an alternative to fmod() function of math.h as I cannot use library functions.

```
unsigned long Function(IntVars_ts IntVars)
{
   float Result = (float) IntVars.Counter_ui32 * IntVars.Factor_fl32;

   //Result = Result % (2^32-1); /* modulo works with integers only */

   return (unsigned long) Result;
}
```

How could this be done in this case? I intended to subtract the unsigned long max value in the while loop, but I am getting lost with casting and possible overflow of two different types as you can see from the output. Doesn't float in this case have enough significant digits to represent the unsigned long value?

Note: Max datatypes values from the output below are different than in my target platform (valid numbers are above)

From your point of view, is there anything else to be concerned about? Rounding errors when converting back to unsigned long should not be an issue in my application if we are talking only about losing the decimal part.

```
/**************************

                            Online C Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

***************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

//#define UI32MAX          ((unsigned long)4294967295UL)
#define UI32MAX          ((unsigned long)18446744073709551615ul)

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned long counter;
    float factor;
    
}IntVars_ts;

unsigned long Function(IntVars_ts IntVars);

int main()
{
    unsigned long start = UI32MAX - 3ul;
    printf("Maximum Unsigned Long %lu\n",(unsigned long)~0);
    printf("Maximum float %f\n\n",FLT_MAX);
    
    IntVars_ts IntVars ={start,1.0f}; /* Constant factor, I only increment the counter\
                                      \in this example */
    
    while(1)
    {
            printf("The unsigned long counter value is %lu\n",IntVars.counter);
            printf("The float counter value is %f\n",(float)IntVars.counter);
            printf("The result is %lu\n\n",Function(IntVars));
            IntVars.counter++;
    }
    


    return 0;
}

unsigned long Function(IntVars_ts IntVars)
{
    float Result = (float)IntVars.counter*IntVars.factor;
    
    while(Result >= (float)UI32MAX)
    {
        printf("Result is %f\n",Result);
        printf("Max is %f\n\n",(float)UI32MAX);
        Result -= (float)UI32MAX;
    }
    
    return (unsigned long)Result;
}
```

```
Output of the previous code is following:

/tmp/z2jTCSG5B0.o
Maximum Unsigned Long 18446744073709551615
Maximum float 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

The unsigned long counter value is 18446744073709551612
The float counter value is 18446744073709551616.000000
Result is 18446744073709551616.000000
Max is 18446744073709551616.000000

The result is 0

The unsigned long counter value is 18446744073709551613
The float counter value is 18446744073709551616.000000
Result is 18446744073709551616.000000
Max is 18446744073709551616.000000

The result is 0

The unsigned long counter value is 18446744073709551614
The float counter value is 18446744073709551616.000000
Result is 18446744073709551616.000000
Max is 18446744073709551616.000000

The result is 0

The unsigned long counter value is 18446744073709551615
The float counter value is 18446744073709551616.000000
Result is 18446744073709551616.000000
Max is 18446744073709551616.000000

The result is 0

The unsigned long counter value is 0
The float counter value is 0.000000
The result is 0

The unsigned long counter value is 1
The float counter value is 1.000000
The result is 1

The unsigned long counter value is 2
The float counter value is 2.000000
The result is 2

The unsigned long counter value is 3
The float counter value is 3.000000
The result is 3
```

Comment: Re “… I cannot use library functions”: It is okay, you can use library functions. I give you permission.

Comment: [Here is a question about getting a floating-point remainder modulo 2^n.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139283/are-there-any-numbers-that-enable-fast-modulo-calculation-on-floats/49140112#49140112) Once the remainder of `IntVars.Factor_fl32` is taken, it can be converted to `uint32_t` and then the calculation can be completed in integer arithmetic. It uses either library functions or the representation of the floating-point number, though.

Comment: Can you instead assign a special value, such as `LONG_MAX`, if the computation produces a result too large for a `long`?  That would be easier to implement, and in many cases it would make more sense, too.

Comment: For `while(Result >= (float)UI32MAX)`, shouldn't the comparison be `>`?

Comment: Re “Doesn't float in this case have enough significant digits to represent the unsigned long value?”: No. The format commonly used for `float`, binary32, does not have enough bits to represent most `unsigned long` values. Its significand is 24 bits, but `unsigned long` has at least 32. `unsigned long` can represent 4,294,967,296 values in [0, 2^32), but binary32 can represent only  83,886,080 of those, less than 2%.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah unfortunately it isn't up to you to give me permission  The calculation has to be done in fl32 as the factor can likely be 0,5 or 0,25 and only the result matters to me. The reason behind it is that it's a generic function used across more projects -> the counter is incremented anywhere between every 250us - 4ms and the factor is used to convert the counter value to 1ms ticks which is then returned by the function.

Comment: State all the constraints on the factor, as a subset of the general problem may have easier solutions. If it is limited to certain values like ½ or ¼, that changes the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No that wouldn't work for me, as I said I don't mind the overflow but I need to get a new value each time the function is called. The returned value represents ticks and is used to measure elapsed time (the difference between two returned values of two function calls, here the integer arithmetic still works even with an overflow).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for responding Eric. Okay then I was wrong and the limitation for me will not be the max value of ui32 but the max value of fl32. Regarding the factor, the constraint I mentioned in the question (factor>0) is currently the only constraint and I would love to/should keep it that way if possible. It all depends on other configurations therefore I said it will "likely" be 0,5 or 0,25 (0;10>, but it isn't a constraint at the moment.

Comment: *Long* before you get to the maximum `float` value, and even before you get to the maximum `uint32_t` value, you will be out of the range where `float` provides unit precision.  *That*'s where your upper limit is, because past that point, `(float)counter == (float) (counter+1)`.  With 24 significant bits in a `float`, that limit is 2^24. (which is exactly representable, even though as a `float`, its units bit is not significant).

Comment: @Hi. Why do you want to "I intended to subtract the _unsigned long max value_ in the while loop" and not "I intended to subtract the _unsigned long max value plus one_ in the while loop"?

Comment: Why are you even using float when it is the same speed or sometimes actually **slower** than double precision on todays hardware? Double has a 53 bit mantissa and can store a 32bit unsigned value exactly with plenty of room to spare. What is the original problem that you are trying to solve? What values can scaling factor actually take in your application? If only powers 1/2^N then why is it a float at all?

Answer (score 0):

> In general I don't mind if the result overflows the type unsigned long as long as the value is valid and the remainder of unsigned long is returned. For this reason I assume I need to implement an alternative to fmod() function of math.h as I cannot use library functions.

Given that your `long` is 32 bits wide and `unsigned long long` must be at least 64, computing an intermediate `unsigned long long` (with sufficient care of precision) is a reasonably good way to avoid problems with overflow when the scale factor is greater than 1.  Simply assigning that result to type `unsigned long` will get you the modular reduction you want.  But since this all has dependencies on the sizes of the types involved, it would be better to use the standard explicit-precision integer types here.  Taking sufficient care of precision probably means performing the scaling computation with type `double`, though even then that's not quite enough if your scale factor has fewer than three significant bits to the right of the radix point.  For example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t Function(IntVars_ts IntVars) {
    double Result = (double) IntVars.counter * IntVars.factor;

    // only needed if IntVars.factor exceeds ULONG_MAX:
    double excess = (uint64_t) (Result / UINT64_MAX) * UINT64_MAX;
    Result -= excess;

    uint64_t integer_result = Result;
   
    return integer_result;
}
```

Note well, however, that when the scale factor is less than 1, you have a truncation problem, not an overflow problem such as you asked about.  The above approach is not appropriate for that case if it's important that your successive calls to the function return different results.

Comment: With common FP, `(double) IntVars.counter * IntVars.factor` needs a `24 + 32` or 56-bit precise product to avoid rounding and `double` is somewhat less: 53 bit.

Comment: That's true, @chux-ReinstateMonica.  I've added some commentary about that.  The above approach is still ok for scale factors that are not extremely large, however.

Answer (score 0):

Code should perform a modulo of `UINT32MAX + 1`, not `UINT32MAX`.

If we assume that `FLT_MAX` < 2<sup>128</sup>, which is quite common, divide the `float` by 2<sup>64</sup> and form a whole number multiplier.  Subtract out that multiplier times 2<sup>64</sup> to achieve a modulo `UINT64_MAX + 1`.  Once the `float` in in the range [0...UINT64_MAX+1), code can convert with a cast to get us into integer land with no UB or implementation defined behavior.

Multiplying `unsigned long` or  `unsigned long long` will also perform a modulo `UINT32n + 1` in forming the product.

```
#define FLT_2POW64 (4294967296.0f * 4294967296.0f)

// Note: More code needed to handle FLT_MAX >= 2**64.
unsigned long Function(IntVars_ts IntVars) {
  // Form IntVars.factor mod 2^64
  float factor = IntVars.factor;
  unsigned long long m = (unsigned long long) (factor/FLT_2POW64);
  factor -= m*FLT_2POW64;
  unsigned long long factor64 = (unsigned long long) factor;
  return (unsigned long) (IntVars.counter * factor64);
}
```

---

**2nd effort**

More robust as it handles a wider range and negative `float`.

```
#define FLT_2POW32 4294967296.0f
#define FLT_2POW64 (FLT_2POW32 * FLT_2POW32)

// Convert float to unsigned long modulo 2*32.
// Each *, /, +, -, compare expected to incur modulo but no rounding.
// Only casts cause rounding.
unsigned long float_to_unsigned_long_mod4G(float factor) {
  float afactor = factor < 0 ? -factor : factor;
  // Does factor has some significant bits that can be ignored as they are
  // multiples of UINT32_MAX + 1?
  if (afactor >= FLT_2POW32) {
    // Move values bits 2**0, 2**1, 2**2, ... 2**31 into the fraction.
    float afactor_scaled = afactor / FLT_2POW32;

    // First test if afactor_scaled is very large.
    // This test only needed if FLT_MANT_DIG + 32 >= 96
    if (afactor_scaled >= FLT_2POW64) {
      // Assuming float has less than 32+64 bits of precision, (24 is common)
      // factor is so large that its least significant bits are not in the uint32_t range
      // and so each bit is a multiple of (UINT32_MAX+1), then the mod is 0.
      return 0;
    }

    // Get rid of the whole number part of afactor_scaled.
    afactor_scaled -= (unsigned long long) afactor_scaled;
    // Put 2**0, 2**1, 2**2, ... 2**31 bits back into their place.
    afactor = afactor_scaled * FLT_2POW32;
  }
  // afactor is in [0 ... FLT_2POW32) range.
  // Drop the fraction.
  unsigned long ufactor = (unsigned long long) afactor;
  if (factor < 0) {
    // Since negative, to get modulo correct, decrement if a fraction existed.
    ufactor = -ufactor - (ufactor != afactor);
  }
  return ufactor & 0xFFFFFFFF;  // Mask needed when unsigned long is more than 32-bit.
}

typedef struct {
  unsigned long counter;
  float factor;
} IntVars_ts;

unsigned long Function(IntVars_ts IntVars) {
  return IntVars.counter * float_to_unsigned_long_mod4G(IntVars.factor);
}
```

Test code

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void testf(float f) {
  unsigned long y = float_to_unsigned_long_mod4G(f);
  printf("f:% -16.9g u32:0X%08lX %lu\n", f, y, y);
}

int main(void) {
  testf(-1);
  const float f[] = { 0, 1, FLT_2POW32, FLT_2POW64 };
  size_t n = sizeof f/sizeof f[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    testf(nextafterf(f[i], -INFINITY));
    testf(f[i]);
    testf(nextafterf(f[i], +INFINITY));
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    testf(nextafterf(-f[i], -INFINITY));
    testf(-f[i]);
    testf(nextafterf(-f[i], +INFINITY));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
f:-1               u32:0XFFFFFFFF 4294967295
f:-1.40129846e-45  u32:0XFFFFFFFF 4294967295
f: 0               u32:0X00000000 0
f: 1.40129846e-45  u32:0X00000000 0
f: 0.99999994      u32:0X00000000 0
f: 1               u32:0X00000001 1
f: 1.00000012      u32:0X00000001 1
f: 4.29496704e+09  u32:0XFFFFFF00 4294967040
f: 4.2949673e+09   u32:0X00000000 0
f: 4.29496781e+09  u32:0X00000200 512
f: 1.8446743e+19   u32:0X00000000 0
f: 1.84467441e+19  u32:0X00000000 0
f: 1.84467463e+19  u32:0X00000000 0
f:-1.40129846e-45  u32:0XFFFFFFFF 4294967295
f:-0               u32:0X00000000 0
f: 1.40129846e-45  u32:0X00000000 0
f:-1.00000012      u32:0XFFFFFFFE 4294967294
f:-1               u32:0XFFFFFFFF 4294967295
f:-0.99999994      u32:0XFFFFFFFF 4294967295
f:-4.29496781e+09  u32:0XFFFFFE00 4294966784
f:-4.2949673e+09   u32:0X00000000 0
f:-4.29496704e+09  u32:0X00000100 256
f:-1.84467463e+19  u32:0X00000000 0
f:-1.84467441e+19  u32:0X00000000 0
f:-1.8446743e+19   u32:0X00000000 0
```