# Power for big numbers modulo m in C

Tags: c, algorithm, function, long-long

I am using the following function to compute powers of big numbers modulo m, where m is any integer,i.e. (a^b)%m

```
long long power(long long x, long long y, long long p)
{
    long long res = 1;      // Initialize result

    x = x % p;  // Update x if it is more than or
                // equal to p

    while (y > 0)
    {
        // If y is odd, multiply x with result
        if (y & 1)
            res = (res*x) % p;

        // y must be even now
        y = y>>1; // y = y/2
        x = (x*x) % p;
    }
    return res;
}
```

But, for some numbers even this function is not working. For example, if I call

```
 power(1000000000000,9897,52718071807);
```

I get a negative number as the output. It happens because of the following reason:
There is a line in the power function:

```
  x = (x*x) % p;
```

When x is big, let's say x=46175307575, the value stored in x after executing x=(x * x)%p becomes negative. I don't understand why it happens. Even if the value of (x * x) crosses the upper range of long long int, I am not storing its value anywhere, I am just storing (x*x)%p whose value should lie between 0 to p. Also, since p doesn't crosses the long long range, how does x cross it? Please tell me why this problem occurs and how to solve this.

Comment: `x*x` is still evaluated as `long long`, you have an signed integer overflow which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Read about [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) which is the most common way to represent negative numbers. And perhaps use `unsigned` numbers to see if it helps? If not then you need a *bignum* library.

Comment: You might want to use some [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: so you need implement multiply by summation

Comment: You should check out this post by chux [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/110790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-integers-under-large-modulo/) is this function:

```
// Returns (a * b) % mod
long long moduloMultiplication(long long a,
                               long long b,
                               long long mod)
{
    long long res = 0;  // Initialize result

    // Update a if it is more than
    // or equal to mod
    a %= mod;

    while (b)
    {
        // If b is odd, add a with result
        if (b & 1)
            res = (res + a) % mod;

        // Here we assume that doing 2*a
        // doesn't cause overflow
        a = (2 * a) % mod;

        b >>= 1;  // b = b / 2
    }

    return res;
}
```

Use it instead of

```
x = (x*x) % p;
```

I.e.,

```
x = moduloMultiplication(x, x, p);
```

and instead of

```
res = (res*x) % p
```

I.e.,

```
res = moduloMultiplication(res, x, p);
```

Comment: `res + a` and `2 * a` both can still overflow.  This approach reduces where OF occurs, yet not eliminated it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcomed to signed  integer overflow and *undefined behavior* (UB).

> I am just storing (x*x)%p whose value should lie between 0 to p.

This is incorrect.  `x*x` may overflow `long long` math and the result is UB.  [@Osiris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695306/power-for-big-numbers-modulo-m-in-c/51701121?noredirect=1#comment90352021_51695306). Sample UB includes a product that is negative with positive operands..

`some_negative_value % some_positive_p` results in a *negative* value. - [see ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359).  This is outside the range `[0...p)`.

The solution is to not overflow signed  integer math.

---

A simple 1st step is to use unsigned integer math.

A full range solution without overflow problem is here [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187257/modular-exponentiation-without-range-restriction)

---

Note OP's code also fails a corner case: `power(some_x, 0, 1)` as it returns 1 when 0 is expected.

```
// Fix
// long long res = 1;
long long res = 1%p;
// or 
long long res = p != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If Mod == (2^63-1) then this solution will not work.**

**Solution: Mod <= 2^62**

(p-1)*(p-1) > 2^63. so there will be overflow. you need to implement multiplication with modulo.

Try with this:

```
long long multiply(long long a,long long b,long long m){
if(b == 0){
    return 0;
}
if(b==1){
    return a%m;
}
if(b&1){
    return ((a%m)+multiply(a,b-1,m))%m;
}
long long x = multiply(a,b>>1,m);
return multiply(x,2,m);
}

long long bigmod(long long a,long long b, long long m){
if(b == 0){
    return 1;
}
if(b == 1){
    return a%m;
}
if(b & 1){
    return multiply(a%m,bigmod(a,b-1,m),m);
}
long long x = bigmod(a,b>>1,m);
return multiply(x,x,m);
}
```

Comment: `(a%m)+multiply(a,b-1,m)` and `x<<1` can still overflow.  This approach reduces where OF occurs, yet not eliminated it.

Comment: how (x<<1) be overflow?

Comment: (a%m)+multiply(a,b-1,m) here used `+` not `*`

Comment: multiply(a,b-1,m) return %m res

Comment: how (x<<1) be overflow? --> `multiply(LLONG_MAX-1, 2, LLONG_MAX);`

Comment: `(a%m)+multiply(a,b-1,m)` can overflow too.  Try `multiply(LLONG_MAX-1, 2, LLONG_MAX)`.

Comment: A solution, see  [`addmodmax()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187257/modular-exponentiation-without-range-restriction) is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51701121/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from solution mentioned by @Doug Currie, you can also use 128 bits data type `__int128`.

```
long long pow(long long a, long long b, long long mod)
{
    __int128 res = 1;
    while(b > 0)
    {
        if(b&1)
        {
            res = (res*a);
            res = res%mod;
        }
        b = b>>1;
        a = ((__int128)a*a)%mod;
    }
    return res;
}
```