# Round Constants in Keccak

Tags: c, cryptography, bit-manipulation, sha-3, keccak

Recently, just for the heck of it, I've been playing around with an attempt at implementing Keccak, the cryptographic primitive behind SHA-3. I've run into some issues however, specifically with calculating the round constants used in the "Iota" step of the permutation.

Just to get it out of the way: *Yes. I know they are round **constants**. I know I could hard code them as constants. But where's the fun in that?*

I've specifically been referencing the [FIPS 202 specification document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) on SHA-3 as well as the Keccak team's own [Keccak reference](https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf). However, despite my efforts, I can't seem to end up with the correct constants. I've never dealt with bit manipulation before, so if I'm doing something the complete wrong way, feel free to let me know.

rc is a function defined in the FIPS 202 standard of Keccak that is a linear feedback shift register with a feedback polynomial of `x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1`.

The values of `t` (specific to SHA-3) are defined as the set of integers that includes `j + 7 * i_r`, where i_r = {0, 1, ..., 22, 23} and j = {0, 1, ..., 4, 5}.

The expected outputs (the round constants) are defined as follows: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000008082, 0x800000000000808a,
0x8000000080008000, 0x000000000000808b, 0x0000000080000001,
0x8000000080008081, 0x8000000000008009, 0x000000000000008a,
0x0000000000000088, 0x0000000080008009, 0x000000008000000a,
0x000000008000808b, 0x800000000000008b, 0x8000000000008089,
0x8000000000008003, 0x8000000000008002, 0x8000000000000080,
0x000000000000800a, 0x800000008000000a, 0x8000000080008081,
0x8000000000008080, 0x0000000080000001, and 0x8000000080008008.

rc Function Implementation

```
uint64_t rc(int t)
{
    if(t % 255 == 0)
    {
        return 0x1;
    }

    uint64_t R = 0x1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= t % 255; i++)
    {
        R = R << 0x1;
        R |= (((R >> 0x0) & 0x1) ^ ((R >> 0x8) & 0x1)) << 0x0;
        R |= (((R >> 0x4) & 0x1) ^ ((R >> 0x8) & 0x1)) << 0x4;
        R |= (((R >> 0x5) & 0x1) ^ ((R >> 0x8) & 0x1)) << 0x5;
        R |= (((R >> 0x6) & 0x1) ^ ((R >> 0x8) & 0x1)) << 0x6;
        R &= 0xFF;
    }

    return R & 0x1;
}
```

rc Function Call

```
for(int i_r = 0; i_r < 24; i_r++)
{

    uint64_t RC = 0x0;

    // TODO: Fix so the limit is not constant
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        RC ^= (rc(j + 7 * i_r) << ((int) pow(2, j) - 1));
    }

    printf("%llu\n", RC);
}
```

Any help on this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: @user3386109 Not sure how I forgot that – thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Note: `t % 255` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359) `t mod 255` when `t < 0`.  It appears `t` is never negative with `j + 7 * i_r`.

Comment: With an integer problem, floating point `pow(2, j)` only adds complications.  Consider `(1u << j)` instead.

Comment: Why `printf("%llu\n", RC);` to print a `uint64_t` in decimal?  I'd expect `printf("0x%" PRIX64 "\n", RC);` to print a `uint64_t` in hexadecimal.  What was the "wrong" output you received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some random changes to the code and now it works. Here are the highlights:

1. The `j` loop needs to count from 0 to 6. That's because 2^6-1 = 63. So if `j` is never 6, then the output can never have the MSB set, i.e. an output of 0x8... is not possible.
2. Using the `pow` function is generally a bad idea for this type of application. `double` values have a nasty habit of being slightly lower than desired, e.g. 4 is actually 3.99999999999, which gets truncated to 3 when you convert it to an `int`. Doubtful that was happening in this case, but why risk it, since it's easy to just multiply variable `shift` by 2 on each pass through the loop.
3. The maximum value for `t` is 7*23+6 = 167, so the `% 255` does nothing (at least with the value of `i` and `t` in this code). Also, there's no need to treat `t == 0` as a special case. The loop won't run when `t` is 0, so the result is 0x1 by default.
4. Implementing a linear feedback shift register is quite simple in C. Each term in the polynomial corresponds to a single bit. `x^8` is just 2^8 which is `0x100` and `x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1` is `0x71`. So whenever bit `0x100` is set, you XOR the result by `0x71`.

Here's the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t rc(int t)
{
    uint64_t result = 0x1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        result <<= 1;
        if (result & 0x100)
            result ^= 0x71;
    }

    return result & 0x1;
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        uint64_t result = 0x0;
        uint64_t shift = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            uint64_t value = rc(7*i + j);
            result |=  value << (shift - 1);
            shift *= 2;
        }            
        printf("0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor: No real reason in using `uint64_t shift`.  `unsigned shift` would suffice.