# Converting a negative decimal into binary in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I'm currently working on a program that (among others) has to convert a decimal number into binary, octal & hexadecimal.
This already works with this code:

```
    int e = 0;
    }
        while(i != 0){
            str[e] = (i%b) + '0';
            i = i / b;
            if(str[e] > '9'){
                str[e] = str[e] + 7;
            }
            e++;

    }
    if(vorzeichen == -1){
        str[e] = '1';
        e++;
    }
    if(b == 16){
        str[e] = 'x';
        str[e+1] = '0';
    }
    else if(b == 8){
        str[e] = '0';
    }
}
```

b is the base (2 for binary, 8 for octal & 16 for hexa) and i is the number that i want to convert. 
This gives out a string of characters which i then reverse to get the correct number. Now if i try this with negative numbers, it gives out strings not only containing 0 and 1 but also /, which is '0' -1 on the ASCII table. For octal and decimal it also gives out characters below the '/' on the ASCII table. I've attempted different possible solutions but none seemed to give the desired result. What I read on the internet is that I have to use the 2s Complement I'm stuck trying to use it. It just doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `snprintf(str, size_of_str, "%o", integer_value)`? Replace `"%o"` with `"%x"` for hexadecimal. For binary I would recommend using bitwise operations like shifting and AND.

Comment: I can't use library functions

Comment: Then I suggest you take some time to [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This is the sort of situation where I suggest writing the algorithm on **paper** first and see how it behaves for different inputs. Once you have something solid going, it's easy to write it in code. Take your time to learn.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display a negative decimal you just can convert your `int` to a `unsigned int` like this :

```
unsigned int value = (unsigned int)i;
```

Now you only have to use `value` instead of `i` in your program and it will be fine.
Here's a good explanation of why : [Converting negative decimal to binary](https://superuser.com/questions/975684/converting-negative-decimal-to-binary)

Answer (score 1):

When converting between different bases/radixes, always work on unsigned integer types.

Let's say you have `long num` you wish to convert.  Use an `unsigned long u`. To represent negative values in two's complement format, you can use

```
if (num < 0)
    u = 1 + (~(unsigned long)(-num));
else
    u = num;
```

or even shorter,

```
unsigned long  u = (num < 0) ? 1 + (~(unsigned long)(-num)) : num;
```

This works on all architectures (except for `num == LONG_MIN`, in which case the above is technically undefined behaviour), *even those that do not use two's complement internally*, because we essentially convert the *absolute value* of `num`. If `num` was originally negative, we then do the two's complement to the unsigned value.

---

In a comment, chux suggested an alternative form which does not rely on UB for `num == LONG_MIN` (unless `LONG_MAX == ULONG_MAX`, which would be horribly odd thing to see):

```
unsigned long  u = (num < 0) ? 1 + (~((unsigned long)(-1 - num) + 1)) : num;
```

This may look "uglier", but a sane C compiler should be able to optimize either one completely away on architectures with two's complement integers. chux's version avoids undefined behaviour by subtracting the negative `num` from `-1`, thus mapping `-1` to `0`, `-2` to `1`, and so on, ensuring that all negative values are representable as a nonnegative `long`. That value is then converted to `unsigned long`. This gets incremented by one, to account for the earlier `-1`. This procedure yields the correct negation of `num`.

In other words, to obtain the absolute value of a `long`, you can use

```
unsigned long  abs_long(const long  num)
{
    return (num < 0) ? (unsigned long)(-1 - num) + 1u : (unsigned long)num;
}
```

Comment: Good approach that does not rely on  _two's complement internally_.  Corner oops: "It is UB with 2's complement `i == INT_MIN` and `-num`.

Comment: @chux: I'm sure you mean `LONG_MIN`, as I'm using `long`, not `int`. I'm not sure it is worth avoiding the Undefined Behaviour here, nor how would one do so portably without an even larger integer type.  Suggestions?

Comment: Yes `LONG_MIN` was meant, not `INT_MIN`.  To avoid a larger type, `1 + (~((unsigned long)(-1 - num) + 1));` (correct, but ugly) or other code.

Comment: @chux: Is there anything in the C standards that says `LONG_MIN+LONG_MAX` cannot be less than -1, or greater than 0? If not, `LONG_MIN` is not the only case that needs special care.

Comment: Yes, "LONG_MIN+LONG_MAX cannot be less than -1, or greater than 0"  is a consequence of C11 §6.2.6.2 2.  On a pedantic note, `LONG_MAX == ULONG_MAX` is possible yet not have come across such a machine for decades.  IMO, OP's goal lacks clarity for a highly portable solution- yet good enough solutions can be had.

Comment: @chux: Convinced, thus added the suggestion. Let me know if I mischaracterized or mistyped anything.

Answer (score 0):

**`%` is the remainder function, not *mod*.**

With `b==2`, `i%b` returns [-1, 0, 1].  This is not the needed functionality for `str[e] = (i%b) + '0';`  See [... difference between “mod” and “remainder”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)

This is the cause of `'/'` and "also gives out characters below the '/' ".

---

**Build up the string from the "right"**

With a 2's complement `int`, a simple approach is to convert to `unsigned` and avoid a negative result from `%`.  Since code is using `%` to extract the *least* significant digit, walk the buffer from right to left.

```
#include <limits.h>

...
unsigned u = i;

// make a temporary buffer large enough for any string output in binary
//           v------v Size of `u` in "bytes"
//           |      |   v------v Size of a "byte" - commonly 8
char my_buff[sizeof u & CHAR_BIT + 1];
int e = 0;

// Form a pointer to the end so code assigns the least significant digits on the right
char *p = &my_buff[sizeof my_buff - 1];

// Strings are null character terminated
*p = '\0';

// Use a `do` loop to insure at least one pass. Useful when `i==0` --> "0"
do {
  p--; 
  p[e] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[u%b];  // Select desired digit
  u = u / b;
} while (u);

// "prepend" characters as desired
if(b == 16){
  *(--p) = 'x';
  *(--p) = '0';
}
else if(b == 8 && i != 0){
  *(--p) = '0';
}

strcpy(str, p);
```