# How do I use modulo arithmetic to implement caesar cipher

Tags: c, modulo

I am trying to perform a wrap around of the ASCII alphabet characters in order to perform a shift from a key. For example, if the key is 2 then shift the letter `A` to become `C`. But, how do I wrap around `Z` in order to get to `B` using modulus arithmetic?

I am trying to implement the following formula:

```
ci = (pi + key) % 26;
```

Where `ci` is the `i`th ciphered letter and `pi` is the `i`th letter to be ciphered.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to work with "relative" values, rather than absolute values.

Use something like

```
ci = ((pi - 'A' + key) % 26 ) + 'A';
```

Character integer constants stores the encoded values, in this case, [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). Here, `'A'` starts from an offset (decimal value of 65), not from 0. So, before you can *wrap* the result using a `% 26` operation, you need to get that offset out. Once the calculation is done, add the offset back to get the proper ASCII representation.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already shown the basic concept of subtracting the offset of ASCII letters, but you have to be careful in when crossing from capital to non capital letters, as there are some symbols in between which I guess you want to avoid. I have added some logic that enables negative shifts and keeps the letter within capital letter or non capital letter space and tests whether it is a letter at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS 65
#define ASCII_LETTER_OFFS 97
#define NUM_OF_LETTERS 26

char shift_letter (char letter, short shift)
{
  char ci;
  short shift_lcl = shift % NUM_OF_LETTERS;
  if (shift_lcl >= 0)
  { // shift in positive direction
  }
  else
  { // shift in negative direction 
   shift_lcl = NUM_OF_LETTERS + shift_lcl;
  }

  if (letter >= ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS && letter < ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS + NUM_OF_LETTERS)  
    {// its a capital letter
      ci =
    (letter + shift_lcl - ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS) % NUM_OF_LETTERS +
    ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS;
    }
  else if (letter >= ASCII_LETTER_OFFS && letter < ASCII_LETTER_OFFS + NUM_OF_LETTERS) 
    {// its a non capital letter
      ci =
    (letter + shift_lcl - ASCII_LETTER_OFFS) % NUM_OF_LETTERS +
    ASCII_LETTER_OFFS;
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("This was not a letter!\n");
      ci = 0;
    }
  return ci;
}

int main ()
{
  char test_letter = 'a';
  short test_shift = -53;
  char shifted_letter = 0;
  shifted_letter = shift_letter (test_letter, test_shift);
  printf("%c +  %d = %c", test_letter, test_shift, shifted_letter);
}
```

Comment: Note: Unexpected results with `test_shift < 0`. Also off-by-1 with `letter <= ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS + NUM_OF_LETTERS` which should be `letter < ASCII_CAP_LETTER_OFFS + NUM_OF_LETTERS`.  `<=` --> `<` in 2 places.

Comment: Thanks for that hint @chux. I've made some corrections. A negative `shift` is now possible ( by adding `NUM_OF_LETTERS` which makes it a shift in positive direction)

Comment: Good improvement.  Also for your design review, why `short` in `short shift` vs `int`?  Usually `short` makes sense for arrays to reduced size.  `int` is the usual workhorse type.

Answer (score 0):

Deeper

```
 ci = ((pi - 'A' + key) % 26) + 'A';
```

as well answered by [@Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886435/2410359) generates the expected encoded A-Z when `key` is non-negative and not too large.  It reduces `pi` with `- 'A'` so the value is in the `[0...25]` range and the re-offsets it after the `%` calculation.

To work for the **full** `int` range of `key` takes a little more code.

- Reduce `key` range `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]` with the functional equivalent range of `[-25 ... 25]` with `key % 26`.  This step is important to prevent `int`overflow with `pi - 'A' + key`.  This can be done once if a number of letters need encoding.
- Add 26.  This insures negative keys are moved to positive ones.

  ```
  ci = ((pi - 'A' + key%26 + 26) % 26 ) + 'A';
  ```

---

Note: In C, `%` is not the *mod* operator, but the *remainder* operator.  Functional differences occur with `a%b` when `a` and/or `b` are negative.  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)