# how to shift down alphabet characters in a cyclic way?

Tags: c

i want to find the alphabet charachter that is 7 charachters before mine ,so i wrote this function to do so and it works fine :

```
char find7_before(char letter){
    switch (letter){
        case 'g':
          return 'z';
          break;
        case 'f':
          return 'y';
          break;
        case 'e':
          return 'x';
          break;
        case 'd':
          return 'w';
          break;
        case 'c':
          return 'v';
          break;
        case 'b':
          return 'u';
          break;
        case 'a':
          return 't';
          break;
        default:
        return (char)(((int)letter) - 7);
    }
}
```

but i think i can do it in a smarter way without all of these cases but i just can't figure it out ! (i figured how to find 7 letters after in a cyclic way ) any help or an idea or a hint ?
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ASCII with continuous `['a' , 'z']`...

Simply "mod 26".

```
letter = ((letter - 'a' - 7) mod 26) + 'a';
```

Yet C does not have a *Euclidean mod* operator.
See [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/2410359)

So create a *Euclidean mod* function - save for later use.

```
int modulo_Euclidean(int a, int b) {
  int m = a % b;
  if (m < 0) {
    // m += (b < 0) ? -b : b; // avoid this form: it is UB when b == INT_MIN
    m = (b < 0) ? m - b : m + b;
  }
  return m;
}



letter = modulo_Euclidean(letter - 'a' - 7, 26) + 'a';
```

---

Alternately code can take advantage that `'a'` has a value of 97 and not subtract so much that `letter - ('a'%26) - 7` becomes negative.

```
letter = (letter - ('a'%26) - 7)%26 + 'a';
```

---

Pedantic code would not assume *continuous `['a' , 'z']`* and perform more elaborate code.

Answer (score 1):

subtract 'a' (so now it's in 0-25), subtract 7, and mod 26. Then add 'a' again so it's back to a char.

Comment: While ASCII is in common use, the C standard does not guarantee that the letters a-z or A-Z are consecutive in the execution character set. A program should not rely on this unless it is a documented prerequisite.

Comment: but how to do mudolo for a negatibe number ?

Comment: char find7_before(char ch){
    unsigned char tmp;
    tmp=(ch-'a')-7;
    tmp = (tmp%26)+'a';
    return tmp;
}

Comment: Re: the negative result in the mod: instead of subtracting 7, just add 19 instead (26-7).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the clearest and simplest way is to use an `if` statement:

```
char find7_before(char letter) {
    char value = letter - 7;
    if (value < 'a') {
        value += 26;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The precondition here is the letter is between `'a'` and `'z'`, inclusive.

This technique generalizes as well:

```
char findn_before(char letter, int n) {
    char value = letter - n;
    if (value < 'a') {
        value += 26;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Precondition on `letter` is the same as before; `n` must be between 0 and 26, inclusive.