# What's wrong with my code with modulus here? (C)

Tags: c, modulus

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int x = 10^2;
  long a = 4000465006540123; //(16 places)
  long b = 4000465006540123 % x;
  
  printf("%li\n", b);
}
```

When I ran the code, (it compiled properly), the code printed out '3'. Isn't it supposed to print out '23' instead, as x is 100, not 10?

Comment: `^` is not the power operator in C. It is bitwise XOR. Do basic debugging. At least print out the values to check.

Answer (score 5):

`int x = 10^2;` same `int x = 8;` as `^` is the exclusive-or operator.

Use `int x = 100;` or `10*10`.

---

Note: In C,  `%` is the *remainder* operator than a *modulus* one.  [Negative results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359) of `a%b` occur when `a < 0`.