# Is there a reverse to Modulus in C

Tags: c, reverse, modulus, modulo, math.h

It's been over thirty years since my high-school algebra so pardon my ignorance due to senility. Is there a inverse to modulus in C language. Such that one could solve the reverse of a previous statement called.

Quite simply :

x = y % 128

How do I solve for y, using C code, if x is known.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is fundamentally a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: It's a semantic not logic question granted but a programming question none the less.

Comment: "Is there a inverse to modulus in C language." --> C lacks a proper modulus for `int`, let alone an inverse one.  See [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/2410359).

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I voting to re-open as there are important differences and limitations  between the mathematical Modulus and C's remainder operator `%`.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, `y` can be solved in such format

```
x + 128*k
```

where `k` is any integer

Comment: ok thanks for the input I see the dilema with modulus.

Comment: In C, `%` is the _remainder, not _modulus_. No difference when `y` and 128 are positive.     `x + 128*k` work OK when `x,k >= 0`, but falls apart otherwise.