# How to printing all 8 neighbors in a 2D vector (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c++, vector, periodicity

I am attempting to access **ALL** 8 neighbors of an index on a 2D vector.

I then try to do the following pseudocode to find all 8 neighbors

```
cout << grid[columnindex-(-1->1)][rowIndex-(-1->1)] << endl;
```

However, when I do this I get a **segmentation fault**. I am unsure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a segmentation fault.

Code is indexing outside array bounds with negative indices.
Index calculation needs to wrap around. Use modulo arithmetic.

```
// cout << grid[c-incc][r-incr] << endl;
int ci = (c-incc + vecSize)%vecSize;
int ri = (r-incr + veciSize)%veciSize;
cout << grid[ci][ri] << endl;
```

---

Code uses `(c-incc + vecSize)%vecSize;` rather than `(c-incc)%vecSize;` to deal with `c-incc < 0` as `%` is not the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), but a [remainder operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359).