# Modulo operator in c

Tags: c, operator-keyword, modulo

I am new to programming . I knew that modulo operator gives remainder for example 7%2=1 but I didn't understand how 1%10= 1 . Can someone please explain it.

Comment: If you have 1, you can take away 0 times 10. How much do you have left?

Comment: you are trying to say that we can write 1 as 10*0+1 where 1 is acting as a remainder.

Comment: Yes, that would be a way to put it.

Comment: C lacks a true _modulo_ operator.  `%` is better thought of as the _remainder_ operator.  [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

When the `dividend` is **smaller** than the `divisor`, then the `dividend` itself is the remainder. means in your case `1%10` is `1`

**Points to remember regarding the '%' operator :**

1. When the dividend is greater than the divisor, it will give the remainder.

`10 % 3 = 1`

2. When the dividend is smaller than the divisor, then the dividend itself is the remainder.

`3 % 10 = 3`

Comment: you are trying to say that we can write 1 as 10*0+1 where 1 is acting as a remainder.

Comment: i hope now you will be able to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
1 % 10 =    10 ) 1 ( 0
                -0
               ------
     Remainder = 1
```

Comment: ya I'm trying to say this that we can write 1 as 10*0+1 where 1 act as remainder

Comment: yes.Dividend = Divisor x Quotient + Remainder

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example, when you say that 7%2 =1, it means the remainder is 1 and the quotient would be 3.

Similarly for 1%10,when we divide 1 by 10, the quotient is 0 but the remainder comes out to be 1.

Therefore 1%10=1.