# Find the remainder after dividing the sum of two integers by the third

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a solution to a task. My code passed only 3 autotests. I checked that the solution satisfies the max/min cases. Probably there are situations when my code is not valid.

**Description of the task**: Find the remainder after dividing the sum of two integers by the third.

**Input**: The first line of input contains two integers A and B (-10^18 ≤ A, B ≤ 10^18). The second line contains an integer C (2 ≤ C 10^9).

**Output**: Print the remainder of dividing A + B by C.

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
// int64_t
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdint.h>

// #include <math.h>

// 3 tests passed
int main() {
    int64_t a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    // a = pow(-10, 18);
    // b = pow(-10, 18);
    // // c = pow(10, 9);
    // c = 3;

    // c = pow(10, 18) - 20;
    // c = 1000000000000000000 + 1;
    // c = 1000000000000000000 + 2;


    // std::cout << a << std::endl;
    // std::cout << b << std::endl;
    // std::cout << c << std::endl;

    std::cout << (a + b) % c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guess it is already be answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122038/remainders-of-two-integers-when-divided-by-another-integer-n)

Comment: what test case fails? In the code in comments you are using `pow` which can easily produce wrong/unexpected results when used with integers. `pow` is not made to be used with integers.

Comment: The range of an `int64_t` is +/- ~9.2e18 ... so why not just `(A + B) % C` ?

Comment: @Zenek that quesitons is about whether `a % b + c%b == (a+c)%b` holds. Not relevant here.

Comment: is this the code that fails? Or is it the code in comments? Also you should include the input that leads to wrong output. If you don't know what fails you cannot fix it

Comment: Please read about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)!!!

Comment: btw `pow(-10, 18);` is the same as `pow(10, 18);` I think you wanted `-pow(10,18);`, but consider comment above, `std::pow` is not for integers

Comment: the code looks fine. Its not clear what you are asking

Comment: Do you have an example of the failed tests? It may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder

Comment: Please provide link to a task. Note in case of negative values there is ambiguity how modulo should be calculated. C++ standard says integer division is rounded toward to zero, but in modular arithmetic integer division is rounded down. This leads to different results of modulo for negative values.

Comment: @Marek But, in C++, `%` is actually the *remainder* operator, not the modulo operator.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ok I used wrong wording.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I don't have test cases data. I just send the code to the system and get the number of passed tests. Commented out code - I used to test myself. Thanks for pointing out the fact that `std::pow()` is not for integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that in C++ reminder for negative values:

- was implementation defined until C++11
- integer division is rounded towards zero since C++11 which makes reminder negative sometimes.

Now most probably in your task modulo result should be always in range `<0, C)` (or written differently  `<0, C - 1>`). So to handle cases where `A + B` is negative, you have to take this into account that reminder may be negative.

So your code can look like this:

```cpp
nt main() {
    int64_t a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    std::cout << (a + b) % c + ((a + b) % c < 0) * c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Which basically adds `c` to result if result is negative and makes result inside required range. (assuming `c` is positive).

Comment: Thank you! You really understood my problem correctly. Previously, I used the operator only for positive numbers, but now I fell for the intricacies of working with a negative number.

Comment: Just to clarify. C++ is close to hardware and must support many platforms. So "implementation defined" was used initially to cover strange early processors which were doing that in different way. After processors design of division unified and support for older platforms was no longer needed, more strict rule has been introduced into a C++11 standard. Note other languages may enforce other rules.

Comment: Yes, I checked different cases for Python and was surprised by the difference  in results!

Answer (score 2):

[Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in C++ uses truncated division, i.e., the result of `x % y` is negative if `x` is negative.

To obtain a non-negative result congruent to `(a + b) % c`, you can use `((a + b) % c + c) % c`.

Comment: stilling my comment ;).

Comment: @MarekR Sorry, this is my first answer on stackoverflow. Your comment has not been posted when I started writing this answer. Should I delete it?

Comment: @MarekR where? I see your comment with the same link but not with the same contents.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk Actually the links are different (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Moreover, the first link has more emphasis on math, while the second link describes various methods used in programming languages to calculate the remainder (truncated divison, floored division, etc.).

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks. Then I even less understand what Marek meant by "stilling" his comment. Also, your answer was the first, so you could not steal from his or anyones answer either (and you have different formula for non-negagivizing modulo operation result which is easier, though maybe less efficient due to additional %). Anyway, I don't think your answer should be deleted.

Comment: I think stilling means satisfying/fulfilling open issues from his comment to his satisfaction (instead of stealing).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the point of the exercise is to handle overflows and underflow by realizing that the remainder of the sum is the sum of the remainder modulo `c`.

That's what my magic-8 ball says anyway. If that's not the solution the provide the failed input and expected and actual output.