# How to find year using mod function?

Tags: c++

I want to know the mod function.  It's like we've been searching for years after using the mod function in Excel.  Can we do the same in c++?

For example, when mod in Excel,
Id = 199734902138
= mod(id,100000000)
As the answer,
34902138
Then id - 34902138
As the answer,
199700000000
Then 199700000000/100000000
Then we can get as the answer 1997
This is the year 1997

How to do the same thing in c++ using mod as mentioned above?  I want to know that.  Can you please help with that?

Comment: Exactly the same way. But it’s much easier to just divide, there’s no need for modulo and subtraction

Comment: How to do that? can you please send me the code? I need it as I said earlier.

Comment: You literally do the division you showed in your question and that’s it

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
 int id;
 int year;
 int mod;
 
 cout << "Enter Your ID Number : ";
 cin >> id;
 
 year = mod (id/10000000);
 cout << year;
 return 0;
}

Comment: Here is the code.

Comment: mod function is not working. I need to know about how it work?

Comment: `auto stupidTime = 199734902138; auto year = stupidTime / 100000000;`

Comment: I want to extract 1997 from 199734902138 using mod function.

Comment: As we keep saying, you do _not_ need to do that because integer division will do it for you. You could subtract the modulo first, but that's completely and utterly pointless _unless_ you are using floating-point values. And whether or not that's the case is currently anybody's guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo doesn't find year, it returns the remainder after a division.

The modulo operator is `%`.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int x;
    x = 10 % 8; 

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // output is 2
    return 0;
}
```

Given your example, the following code would perform the same order of operations as  your question. Notice the use of the long long int data type. Values this high (12-digit numbers) can only be expressed using long long int type.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

// declare variable id = 199734902138 and initial answer
long long int id = 199734902138;
long long int answer = id % 100000000;

// answer is now 199700000000 
answer = id - answer;

//final calculation, divide the answer by 100000000
id = answer / 100000000;

// output id for verification 
std::cout << id <<std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

As mentioned, this is all a bit superfluous as a simple divide operation will yield the same result, however if these steps need to be explicitly used in your calculation, then the code above would fit.

Comment: This really is taking the round-about way.

Comment: Yeah, its a bit odd to say the least. I was mostly just trying to answer based on the context of the info given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, % is modulo operator, like

```
long int ID = 199734902138;
long int m = ID % 100000000; // results 34902138
int year = (ID - m) / 100000000; // results 1977
```

But a simple division does the same thing in C++, because an integer divided by an integer results another integer

```
int year = 199734902138 / 100000000; // results 1977
```

Comment: `%` is the [remainder operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/2410359), not modulo.