# c program: for loop rows and columns

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to know how the modulo operator is used here

Input and output are as follows:

```
Input : 6

1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8 9
5 6 7 8 9 0
6 7 8 9 0 1
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int i, j, n;
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
 
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            printf ("%d ", (i+j)%10);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's used to keep the output between numbers 0-9 and that's about it. If you know how to calculate (i+j)/10 then you know how to calculate (i+j)%10 as well.

Comment: OT: Strictly speaking `%` is **not** a modulo operator. Instead it calculates the remainder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683563/whats-the-difference-between-mod-and-remainder

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is so I'm not sure this will help but... `printf ("%d ", (i+j)%10);` will generate the same as `int x = (i+j) - ((i+j) / 10) * 10; printf ("%d ", x);` In other words... `n % 10` will give a number in the range 0..9 (when n is positive).

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(i+j)%10` calculates `i+j` modulo 10, which means taking the last digit of the sum of `i` and `j`.