# how to solve this without a loop?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, division

we're given 3 numbers y, x, and n. we're asked to find the largest k in case 1 <= k <= n and k % x = y.
for example:
input:  1 2 100
output: 99

what i can write is like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int y, x, n, max = 1;
   scanf("%d %d %d", &y, &x, &n);
   for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
   {
        if ((k % x == y) && (k >= max))
        max = k;
   }
   printf("%d", max);
   return 0;
}
```

it totally works right. but the problem is the program should be written without using any loop or if.
anyone has any idea??

Comment: A recursive function?

Comment: If it's just 3 numbers you can get by with `if` statements.

Comment: can using goto be acceptable ?

Comment: Fateme, what is the range of possible `x, y`?  (Of course `x==0` is a problem.)

Comment: Fateme, "it totally works right." --> try any case where `x <= y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes all numbers are non-negative, `x` is non-zero, and 0 ≤ `y` < `x`.

The largest number satisfying the conditions, if it exists, is `(n-y)/x*x + y`.

Proof:

Let `m` be the largest multiple of `x` not greater than `n-y`. Then `n-y` = `m+r` for some 0 ≤ `r` < `x`. (If `r` were negative, `m` would be greater than `n-y`. If it were `x` or greater, `m` would not be the largest multiple, as `m+x` would be a multiple of `x` not greater than `n-y`.)

Then `(n-y)/x` = `(m+r)/x` = `m`/`x` since integer division discards the remainder. So `(n-y)/x*x` = `m`.

Since `m` is a multiple of `x`, `m % x` = 0. Then `(m+y) % x` = `y`, so `(n-y)/x*x + y` = `y`.

To see this is the largest such number not greater than `n`, observe the next larger number with a remainder of `y` is `(n-y)/x*x + y + x` = `m + y + x` = `m + y + r + (x-r)` = `(n-y) + y + (x-r)` = `n + (x-r)`, and we know `x-r` is positive, so this is greater than `n`.

Note: Regarding the condition 1 ≤ `k`, this is automatically satisfied if `n` is large enough to permit such a solution, since the formula produces the largest `k` ≤ n whose remainder modulo `x` is `y`. If the `k` resulting from the formula does not satisfy 1 ≤ `k`, no solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

I am going for a full range (+ and -) `x, y` answer with no `int` overflow and clearly determine when no solution is possible.

---

Given:

```
1 <= k <= n
k % x == y
```

`k % x == y` implies
`k = quotient * x  + y` where `quotient` is some integer.

---

**When `x == 0`**, then
`any_int % 0` is not defined, so in C we cannot certainly form an answer.
`1 <= n` is also required in all cases.

```
if (x == 0 || n < 1) No_solution;
```

---

**When `x > 0`**, then
`y >= 0` (`positive_int % x is never < 0)` and
`y < x`  (`positive_int % x is always < x`).
With `k % x == y` and `1 <= k <= n`, then
`n >= y` must be true for a solution.

```
if (x > 0 && (y < 0 || y >= x || y > n)) No_solution;
```

After rejecting above *no solution* combinations:

```
quotient * x + y <= n       // leads to ...
quotient <= (n-y)/x         // quotient is >= 0 and overflow not possible
largest_k = (n-y)/x * x + y // largest_k >= 0 and overflow not possible
if (largest_k == 0) No_solution;
```

---

**When `x < 0`**, then
`y >= 0` (`positive_int % x is never < 0)` and
`y < -x` (`positive_int % x is always < -x`).<sup>*1</sup>
(Recall `a%b` is [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359) `a mod b` when negatives values are involved.

```
if (x < 0 && (y < 0 || y > -1 - x || y > n)) No_solution;
```

The rest of the analysis follows the `x > 0` case, except `quotient <= 0`

---

**All together**

```
if (x == 0 || n < 1 || y < 0 || y > n) return No_solution;
if (x > 0 && y >= x) return No_solution;
if (x < 0 && y > -1 - x) return No_solution;

int quotient = (n-y)/x;
int largest_k = quotient * x + y;
if (largest_k == 0) return No_solution;
printf("Largest k: %d\n", largest_k);

// I suspect simplifications possible - maybe later.
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>
`y < -x` could be re-written as `y <= -1 - x`.  This form handles all negative `x` including `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 0):

The given program finds the largest integer k which satisfies the conditions (k % x == y) and (k >= max) for the given values of y, x, and n. This can be done without a loop by using the formula for arithmetic progression.

The largest integer k that satisfies the condition (k % x == y) can be written as k = x * q + y, where q is an integer. So, we need to find the largest q such that x * q + y <= n.

The largest q can be found using the formula q = floor((n - y) / x). Here, floor is the function that rounds down to the nearest integer.

Then, we can compute k as k = x * q + y. If k >= max, then max = k.

Here is the modified code without the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int y, x, n, max = 1;
   scanf("%d %d %d", &y, &x, &n);
   
   int q = floor((n - y) / (double)x); // compute largest q
   int k = x * q + y; // compute k
   if (k >= max) max = k; // update max if necessary
   
   printf("%d", max);
   return 0;
}
```

Note that we need to include the math.h header file for the floor function. Also, we need to cast x to a double before dividing to ensure that the result is a floating-point number.

Comment: With positive values `floor((n - y) / (double)x)` replaceable with `(n - y) / x`.  No  need for floating point in this integer problem.

Comment: Note: uncommon input  like `3 -7 20` returns 24 when 17 is expected.  Using `trunc()` instead of `floor()` solves that as  `%` relies on integer division truncating the fraction, not flooring it.