# Why does expanding this C assignment into 2 lines produce a different result?

Tags: c, underflow

This code produces the (incorrect) result of `255`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0;
    x = (x-1)%16;
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

While this code produces the result `15` which I feel is correct

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0;
    x--;
    x %= 16;
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to use an underflow to my advantage when this unexpected result happened.

Problem does not occur with `unsigned int` or any other unsigned integer type.

Comment: You can turn the first into the second with `x = ((unsigned char)(x-1))%16`.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. What is the mechanism behind that fixing the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/11683?

Comment: @TungstenUmbrella Avoid intermediate negatives: `x = (x-1)%16;` --> `x = (x+16-1)%16;`.

Comment: @TungstenUmbrella "Problem does not occur with unsigned int or any other unsigned integer type."  What happens for you with `unsigned short x = 0;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/4885321) post.
x-1 is implicitly promoted to signed int, effectively becoming `-1`. `-1 % 16` (so "remainder of -1 / 16") is still -1, then it is converted back to unsigned char, which is 255.

Comment: Detail: `(x-1)%16` is not best described as "mod 16", but more like ["remainder 16"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359).  Usually  "-1 mod 16" is considered 15 (Euclidean mod).