# Strange Behaviour with Modulo Operation and Negative Floating Point Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, modulo, python-3.11

The mod operation with negative numbers was not working as expected.
I was trying to get the floating part of a number, and I used `num % 1` to get it, was working, until it was negative, when was negative it worked in a strange way, only while running, when I tested it on the terminal, worked as expected with both signs (+ or -), but when was into the program it worked wrong, I saw someone talking about being an integer, and recommended using `num % 1.0`, but didn't worked, I got the same problem either way.

The `time_difference_minutes % 1` isn't working properly, it's returning
`0.7142857142857126`
But it was supposed to return
`0.285714285714287` (float part)

---

The strange part was, when i did it directly in the prompt, it worked, than I did again just this snippet on a new file
`print(4.285714285714287 % 1)`
And worked, I got the expected, but once I added the "-" signal, it started happening again, but the output was the same every time, I noticed it everytime goes wrong, and I didn't found any explanation about this in specific, other point I noticed was it works on terminal with the "-" signal, just when the program was running it returned wrong.

---

I used the abs() to solve the problem, but I really want to understand what's going wrong here.

---

## Code example:

```
# Constants
AVENUE_LENGTH_KM = 22.5
OLD_SPEED_KMH = 70
NEW_SPEED_KMH = 90

# Calculations
time_taken_old_speed_hours = AVENUE_LENGTH_KM / OLD_SPEED_KMH
time_taken_new_speed_hours = AVENUE_LENGTH_KM / NEW_SPEED_KMH

time_difference_hours = time_taken_new_speed_hours - time_taken_old_speed_hours
time_difference_minutes = time_difference_hours * 60
time_difference_seconds = time_difference_minutes * 60

# Output
print("{:.2f} hours".format(time_difference_hours))
print("{:.0f} minutes and {:.0f} seconds".format(
    time_difference_minutes, (time_difference_minutes % 1) * 60))
print("{:.0f} seconds".format(time_difference_seconds))
```

Comment: Aside: In C, `%` and `fmod()` are the _remainder_, not the _modulo_. [Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)

Comment: I wrote wrong, thanks for the correction!

Comment: To be clear, does you `time_difference_minutes` have a value of about -4.28571?  ... So all you are asking is why `-4.285714285714287 % 1` is 0.7142857142857126 and not 0.285714285714287 or -0.285714285714287?

Comment: I thought using %1 should just give me the decimal part of numbers, because it would divide fully the integer part. It worked fine when I tried it on Terminal. But when I used it in the program (x % 1), I got results that didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Python always maintains the relationship: `a//b * b + a%b == a`.  Since the floor division rounds down for a negative number, the modulus adjusts to compensate.